# Regex - Tempo de processo de replace muito alto

Tags: regex, timer, preg-replace, runtime

Recentemente apos desenvolver um processo, vi que este estava demorando exorbitantes 5~6min a ser executado, algo que deveria demorar no máximo 2s, desta forma comecei a debugar o código com `timers` para saber qual processo estava demorando tanto a ser realizado, e cheguei a este.

```
$html = preg_replace('~[^#]*(<Ajax>[^\~]*?</ajax>)[^#]*~', '$1', $html);
```

O `HTML` que estou fazendo `replace` possui mais de 2 mil linhas então não vou postá-lo aqui mas ele é segue este padrão:

```
<Ajax>
    <Sucesso>True</Sucesso>
    <DadosRetorno><![CDATA[
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btnExportarExtNfe" class="button" value="Exportar resultado completo da pesquisa para arquivo texto" onclick="btnExportarExtNfe_click();" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <table class="painel">
            <tr class="listaHeaderEcac">
                <th><label>#</label></th>
                <th><label>Dt Emit</label></th>
                <th><label>Dt Ent/Sai</label></th>
                <th><label>IE Emit</label></th>
                <th><label>UF Emit</label></th>
                <th><label>CNPJ Emit</label></th>
                <th><label>IE Dest/Remet</label></th>
                <th><label>UF Dest/Remet</label></th>
                <th><label>CNPJ Dest/Remet</label></th>
                <th><label>Mod</label></th>
                <th><label>Série</label></th>
                <th><label>Número</label></th>
                <th><label>Total NF-e</label></th>
                <th><label>Total BC ICMS</label></th>
                <th><label>Total ICMS</label></th>
                <th><label>Total BC ICMS ST</label></th>
                <th><label>Total ICMS ST</label></th>
                <th><label>Sit</label></th>
                <th><label>E/S</label></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="linha"><a onclick="ExibeNfeCompleta('00000000000000000000000000000000000000000020')" style="cuANor:pointer"><img src='../Imagens/lupa.png' alt='Visualizar' border=0></a></span></td>
                <td><span class="linha">03/08/15</span></td>
                <td><span class="linha">03/08/15</span></td>
                <td><span title='Empresa 1' class="linha">000/0000000</span></td>
                <td><span class="linha">AN</span></td>
                <td><span title='Empresa 1' class="linha">00.000.000/0000-00</span></td>
                <td><span title='Empresa 2' class="linha">000/0000000</span></td>
                <td><span class="linha">AN</span></td>
                <td><span title='Empresa 2' class="linha">00000000000000</span></td>
                <td><span class="linha">55</span></td>
                <td><span class="linha">1</span></td>
                <td><span class="linha">00000</span></td>
                <td align="right"><span class="linha">0,00</span></td>
                <td align="right"><span class="linha">0,00</span></td>
                <td align="right"><span class="linha">0,00</span></td>
                <td align="right"><span class="linha">0,00</span></td>
                <td align="right"><span class="linha">0,00</span></td>
                <td><span title='Normal' class="linha">N</span></td>
                <td><span title='Saída' class="linha">S</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div width="000%"><span class="linha">NFes Emitidas até: <strong>00/00/0005 09:01:03</strong></span></div>
        <div width="000%" align="center">
            &nbsp;
            <SPAN title="Linha Inicial e Final da Página">Linhas de 1 a 000</SPAN> - &nbsp;
            <SPAN title="Total de Linhas Recuperadas">Total de Linhas: 000</SPAN>
            <br> &nbsp;
            <SPAN title="Total de Páginas">Páginas: 4</SPAN>
            <br> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <span class="menu4"><b>1</b></span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="javascript:trocaPagina(2);" style="font-weight: bold;color: #000000; text-decoration: underline;" class="LinkNavActive">2</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="javascript:trocaPagina(3);" style="font-weight: bold;color: #000000; text-decoration: underline;" class="LinkNavActive">3</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="javascript:trocaPagina(4);" style="font-weight: bold;color: #000000; text-decoration: underline;" class="LinkNavActive">4</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:trocaPagina(2);" style="font-weight: bold;color: #000000; text-decoration: underline;" class="menu4">Próx.</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:trocaPagina(4);" style="font-weight: bold;color: #000000; text-decoration: underline;" class="menu4">Final</a>
        </div>
        ]]></DadosRetorno>
</Ajax>
```

Ele tem mais algumas `tags` de `header` e `footer` pois isso o replace.
Pelo debug é justamente este `replace` que demora 5~6min.

Alguém saberia o porque de tanta demora?
Alguém pode indicar uma `REGEX` melhor?

Comment: Poderia dizer o motivo de estar fazendo o replace? Já que está manipulando um XML, tentou utilizar XPATH?

Comment: Na verdade estou usando simpleHtmlDom, e o motivo é por cautela quanto aos dados retornados, ja que este html provem de um curl, e como comentei ele vem com algumas tags de header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez mudar o quantificador `[^\~]*?` para `[^\~]*` resolva.

O quantificador "não guloso" `*?` (*lazy*) faz com que para cada caractere casado, a pesquisa vai testar o restante da expressão regular, por isso a demora.

Usando um quantificador "guloso" `*` (*greedy*) a expressão regular vai pesquisar o grupo em questão em todos os caracteres até o fim da *string* ou até que um caractere não case, e depois "volta" pesquisando o restante da expressão regular de trás para frente.

Mas por se tratar de XML, é recomendado usar um interpretador XML e não expressão regular