# O que pode tornar uma expressão regular lenta?

Tags: regex

Já aconteceu aqui no `Stackoverlow` de eu ser recomendado por alguns usuários quanto a evitar o uso de regex, em alguns casos, pois a mesma pode ter uma performance indesejável.

Já ouvi também por aí que, depedendo da forma que uma expressão regular é construída (sendo que, para capturar alguma coisa desejada, pode haver muitas maneiras de fazê-lo com a expressão regular), ela pode ser mais lenta.

Considerando esses fatores:

- O que faz com que a expressão regular seja mais lenta que outras formas de se trabalhar com strings?
- Dependendo do que eu deseje fazer com expressão regulares, pode haver alguma forma de se fazer (com expressão regulares) com que ela se torne mais performática, apenas mudando sua construção?

Por exemplo, uma das expressões abaixo podem ser consideradas "mais rápidas" que as outras?

```
 // Apenas números. Qual é mais rápido?

'teste 123456 teste 123'.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')

'teste 123456 teste 123'.replace(/\D+/g, '')

'teste 123456 teste 123'.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '')
```

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81426/regex-tempo-de-processo-de-replace-muito-alto

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, talvez esse conteúdo possa ser útil http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5136/performance-de-substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-string/5239#5239, aqui ele compara o RegExp com outras formas.

Comment: Para teste de suas expressões você pode usar http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Eu usei muito as referências deste site. http://www.regular-expressions.info e para a pergunta acredito que aqui dá pra dar uma boa idéia do quanto Regex pode pesar para avaliar uma simples *string* http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138705/101

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Resumidamente

- O quão especifica ela é.
- O numero de quantificadores que esta usando.

## O que é uma REGEX

Você deve lembrar que, indiferente da linguagem/biblioteca, regex são [Autômato finito determinístico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aut%C3%B4mato_finito_determin%C3%ADstico), que serão compilados e transformadas em uma maquina de estados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim você deve ter em mente que ela analisa letra por letra (simbolo por simbolo), até verificar se a sentença é valida ou não.

#### Exemplo

Digamos que se tenha a seguinte regex `a(b|c)`. É gerada uma maquina de estados bem simples.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- O 1º estado diz de a letra/simbolo deve ser `a`, obrigatoriamente.
- Caso passe pelo 1º estado o 2º estado pode ser `b` ou `c`.

Se qualquer um dos estados não for comprido ou nenhum dos próximos estados seja encontrado. A sentença é invalida.

- `ab`, `ac` = Valido
- `ba` = Invalido, já não compre o 1º estado que deve ser `a`.
- `aX` = Invalido, `X` não esta nas possibilidade do 2º estado.

## Quantificadores

A analogia dos quantificadores é bem simples.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você gera um estado que aponta para ele mesmo, ou gera um "curto" para não passar por aquele estado (`*`, `{0,`).

### No que eles interferem?

[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94104/14213) tem um pequeno resumo e um boa analogia (Em minha opinião).

Um quantificador vai disser quantas vezes aquele estado pode ser valido. Um estado mal planejado com quantificador infinito pode ser catastrófico. `.*`/`.+`, Exemplo disso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81426/14213). (Aprendi na pratica)

O que ocorre é que ele simplesmente vai continuar seguindo o máximo que pode ate chegar no final da sentença. Quando ele chega no final, faz o caminho inverso, removendo caracteres e verificando se o próximo estado (2º) é satisfeito, no primeiro caractere que satisfaça o próximo estado (2º) ele continua (para o 3º).

Na maioria das vezes não se nota esses problemas pois trabalhamos com `strings` pequenas que o computador simplesmente vai e volta tão rápido que é quase imperceptível.

#### Exemplo

https://regex101.com/r/vrUk3U/1

Por isso ele parou na ultima virgula não na primeira.

## Especificar

Lembre-se de especificar ao máximo o que você quer.
Um bom exemplo de especificação é o inicio `^`.

Você também deve ter um mente que se você não especifica de onde ela deve começar, então ela simplesmente vai começar de qualquer lugar. Exemplo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147441/operador-de-nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-retorna-valor-que-deveria-ser-descartado/147601#147601).

Então para impedir que ela faça testes desnecessários o simples ato de ser especifico já a torna mais rápida.

### Nota

- Algumas REGEX são mais fáceis de se montar utilizando logica inversa. Em vez de pensar no que você precisa, pense no que não precisa.

### Sobre os exemplos

```
'teste 123456 teste 123'.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')

'teste 123456 teste 123'.replace(/\D+/g, '')

'teste 123456 teste 123'.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '')
```

Em termos de REGEX você não vai ter diferença nenhuma, pois as três serão compiladas para `[^0-9]`.
Você pode ter um diferença no tempo de compilação, na qual sua biblioteca vai demorar diferentes tempo para transcrever o que você esta dizendo.

Comment: Melhor explicação sobre regex que ja ví. Excelente.

Answer (score 12):

Este [link](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/) contem uma boa explicação a respeito, cujas ideias eu também explico aqui abaixo, com um exemplo que construí e rodei na minha máquina.

Entradas inválidas podem causar uma performance muito ruim com expressões regulares mal definidas. Um exemplo de expressões regulares mal definidas são as que **reconhecem a entrada de mais de uma maneira possível**, e, por consequência, **tentam reconhecer entradas inválidas de várias formas possíveis**.

De maneira geral, o tempo gasto para reconhecer uma entrada inválida pode aumentar de maneira exponencial com respeito ao número de caracteres `n` da  entrada

**Exemplo**

A expressão regular `xx+y` pode ser escrita também como `(x+x+)+y` . A primeira expressão traduz-se para um autômato finito determinístico, sem backtracking, enquanto que a segunda expressão utiliza backtracking. Quando uma entrada válida é reconhecida, não há problema, pois o autômato encerra a busca imediatamente. Quando uma entrada inválida é fornecida, no entando, o mecanismo de reconhecimento vai tentar todas as formas de reconhecimento possíveis, até ter certeza de que a entrada não pode ser reconhecida pela Regex.

Segue um exemplo de código e sua saída correspondente, na minha máquina. O exemplo é em C#, mas os conceitos são agnósticos de tecnologia:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TesteRegex
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string padraoMau = "(x+x+)+y";
            string padraoBom = "xx+y"; ;
            string[] arrayBom = new string[] { "xxy", "xxxxxxy", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy" };
            string[] arrayMau = new string[] { "xxx", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" };

        Console.WriteLine("---- Backtracking: sim; Entrada válida: sim ----");
        TestaRegex(padraoMau, arrayBom);
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("---- Backtracking: sim; Entrada válida: não ----");
        TestaRegex(padraoMau, arrayMau);
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");

        Console.WriteLine("---- Backtracking: não; Entrada válida: sim ----");
        TestaRegex(padraoBom, arrayMau);
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("---- Backtracking: não; Entrada válida: não ----");
        TestaRegex(padraoBom, arrayMau);
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void TestaRegex(string padrao, string[] array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tamanho da entrada  | Tempo gasto");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            sw.Start();
            Regex.IsMatch(array[i], padrao);
            sw.Stop();                
            Console.WriteLine("                   " + string.Format("{0,2}", array[i].Length) + "|  " + sw.Elapsed.ToString("ss\\.ffffff"));
            sw.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Saída:

```
---- Backtracking: sim; Entrada válida: sim ----
Tamanho da entrada  | Tempo gasto
------------------------------------
                    3|  00.000347
                    7|  00.000021
                   21|  00.000003
                   23|  00.000002
                   27|  00.000002
------------------------------------------------
---- Backtracking: sim; Entrada válida: não ----
Tamanho da entrada  | Tempo gasto
------------------------------------
                    3|  00.000011
                    7|  00.000039
                   21|  00.594714
                   23|  02.359978
                   27|  38.033123
------------------------------------------------
---- Backtracking: não; Entrada válida: sim ----
Tamanho da entrada  | Tempo gasto
------------------------------------
                    3|  00.000043
                    7|  00.000005
                   21|  00.000014
                   23|  00.000017
                   27|  00.000024
------------------------------------------------
---- Backtracking: não; Entrada válida: não ----
Tamanho da entrada  | Tempo gasto
------------------------------------
                    3|  00.000008
                    7|  00.000007
                   21|  00.000019
                   23|  00.000020
                   27|  00.000024
------------------------------------------------
```

O único caso de performance sofrível foi o de **entradas inválidas, numa regex com backtracking** (38 segundos com backtracking versus menos de um milésimo para a versão sem backtracking, para um entrada de tamanho 27).

O problema é que o número de formas de tentar reconhecer um string inválida, na versão sem backtracking, está associado ao [número de partições de um número inteiro](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_parti%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(matem%C3%A1tica)) , que é **exponencial** no tamanho da entrada, o que causa a performance ruim.

Solução: ao definir uma expressão regular, assegure-se de que há uma forma (ou o menor número de formas possível) apenas para reconhecer tanto entradas válidas quanto inválidas. Prefira expressões simples, como xx+y, ao invés de (x+x+)y .

No caso dos exemplos que você forneceu para comparação, eles vão possuir performance similar (boa).

Comment: Outro motivo para evitar regex é que alguns motores de reconhecimento são simplesmente ruins. A implementação de regex para Golang por exemplo não é muito performática atualmente.