# O que é uma Expressão Regular gulosa?

Tags: regex

- O que é uma `Expressão Regular Gulosa`?
- O que diferencia ela da `Expressão Regular Não-Gulosa`?
- `Expressões regulares Gulosas` consomem mais recurso do que as `Não-Gulosas`?

Comment: Agora, quanto as expressões regulares, já que você esta estudando sobre, recomendo a leitura [deste artigo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Valeu @GuilhermeLautert

Comment: "Expressão Regular Gulosa" é o jeito que os gordinhos regularmente se expressam sobre sua própria gula.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Quantificadores

Especificam quantas vezes a instancia anterior deve ser capturada

### Quantificador Guloso

Em geral quando se fala de quantificador guloso se refere ao `*`, pois ele representa 0 ou infinitas vezes, ou seja ele tentara capturar o máximo possível, mas caso não haja o que capturar esta `ok` também.

Entretanto um quantificador guloso também pode ser `{0,}` que tem o mesmo efeito.

Mais alguns :

```
+     // captura o máximo possível, mas deve ocorrer ao menos uma vez
{1,}  // tem o mesmo efeito
```

#### Pensamentos

```
1. {1,5}  // é um quantificador que vai de 1 a 5
2. {1,80} // é um quantificador que vai de 1 a 80
3. {60,80} // é um quantificador que deve ter no mínimo 60 e vai ate 80
```

O `2.` seria mais guloso que o `1.` pois ele casa com ate 80 enquanto o `1.` apenas com 5, já o `3.` ele diz que deve ter ao menos `60` podendo ir ate `80`, o que seria mais guloso ainda pois especifica um mínimo.

#### Analogia

Pense em um pessoa comendo:

- a `1.` diz que come de 1 a 5 kg.
- a `2.` diz que come de 1 a 80 kg.
- a `3.` diz que quer comer de 60 a 80 kg.

### Quantificadores não-guloso

Para fazer o efeito contrario no quantificador guloso se acrescenta o `?`, assim em vez de capturar o máximo ele tenta capturar o mínimo.

Em geral se referencia o `*?`, que casa com o máximo, mas tenta capturar o mínimo, neste caso o mínimo é 0.

#### Um erro comum

```
`teste .*?` // não faz sentido ter o `.*?`, pois ele não vai capturar nada.
```

#### Exemplo de mínimo

```
`teste`.macth(/.*?t/) // enquanto o `.*` iria capturar `test`, o mínimo captura apenas `t`
```

## Performance

O quantificador guloso é mais rápido, pois ele vai comendo ate não dar mais, enquanto o não-guloso é mais lento pois verifica sempre se é o mínimo possível.

#### Analogia

Pensando novamente em pessoas comendo:

- O guloso come ate não ter mais comida.
- O não-guloso come um pouco verifica se é suficiente, então come mais um pouco e verifica se já é suficiente, e assim vai.

Comment: +1 Gostei da analogia :p. É uma boa parábola

Answer (score 16):

**Guloso**: busca até o final da string a ultima ocorrência, ou seja, pega o máximo possível.

Ex.:

**Regex**: `maça .*`
**Input**: `maça melancia laranja`

O que a regex irá pegar é: `maça melancia laranja`

---

**Não Guloso** busca até a primeira ocorrência, ou seja, pega o minimo possível, exemplos: `?`, `{1}`

Ex.:

**Regex**: `maça .*?`
**Input**: `maça melancia laranja`

O que a regex irá pegar é: `maça`

---

> `Expressões regulares Gulosas` consomem mais recurso do que as `Não-Gulosas?`

Analisando a rapida explicação acima, podemos concluir que a **utilização** de uma expressão regular gulosa em textos extensos irá consumir mais processamento e memoria.

Answer (score 10):

Uma Regex gulosa (*greedy*) tenta combinar o maior número de vezes possível o padrão especificado, utiliza-se o  asterisco para definir isso `*`.

Uma expressão não gulosa combina o texto o minimo possível, ao encontrar a primeira ocorrência do padrão ela para.

Algumas expressões gulosas tendem a consumir mais recursos devido a elas analisarem o texto do contrario das não gulosas que analisam parte dele.

Answer (score 4):

As outras respostas já explicaram o que é, mas acho que vale explicar **como** a regex trata internamente os quantificadores gulosos e não-gulosos, até mesmo para esclarecer o que foi dito em [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94104/112052), que afirma que "*o quantificador guloso é mais rápido*" (**só que isso não é sempre verdade, pois depende da expressão e da string sendo verificada**).

E para entender melhor o motivo, vale explicar em detalhes como funcionam os quantificadores "gulosos" (ou "gananciosos" - tanto que em inglês costumam-se chamar [*greedy*](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap)) e suas versões não-gulosas (ou "preguiçosos" - [*lazy*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415757/112052)).

---

Por exemplo, se tivermos esta string:

```
a,b,c,123,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vxw,yz
```

E esta regex: `,.*,\d` (vírgula, zero ou mais caracteres, outra vírgula e um dígito). De acordo com o regex101.com, [esta regex precisa de 48 passos para encontrar um *match*](https://regex101.com/r/3Zg6cy/2/) (a quantidade exata pode variar de uma *engine* para outra, mas em geral, para este exemplo específico, veremos que o quantificador *greedy* demora mais que o *lazy*).

Já se usarmos o quantificador não-guloso/*lazy*, [a regex precisa de apenas 9 passos](https://regex101.com/r/nJFbDN/2/) para encontrar um *match*.

Essa diferença se dá não porque o quantificador guloso tenta pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres, mas sim **por causa da forma como isso é feito**. E como ele faz isso? No regex101.com [é possível *debugar* todos os passos da *engine*](https://regex101.com/r/3Zg6cy/2/debugger), mas basicamente ela faz o seguinte:

- A regex vai avançando na string até encontrar a primeira vírgula (no caso, é a que está logo depois do "a")
- O `.*` é guloso/*greedy*, então ele vai até o final da string (já que o ponto corresponde a [qualquer caractere](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), e como o `*` é guloso, então ele pega tudo de uma vez, avançando até o final da string). No regex101 (no [link já citado](https://regex101.com/r/3Zg6cy/2/debugger)) você pode ver esta ação no passo 3
- Depois a regex verifica a segunda vírgula da expressão (a que está depois do `.*`). Mas como a regex foi até o final da string, não há vírgula posterior, então ela faz o *backtracking*, ou seja, ela volta uma posição e tenta novamente. No caso, ela volta uma posição antes do fim (ou seja, para o "z"), e vê se depois dele tem uma vírgula. Como não tem, ela volta mais uma posição (para o "y"), vê se depois tem uma vírgula, e como não tem, volta mais uma posição e encontra a vírgula que está antes do `y`

  - Apenas para lembrar, até aqui, a regex pegou tudo da primeira vírgula (depois do "a") até a última vírgula (antes do "y"), e isso tudo corresponde ao trecho `,.*,`. Ou seja, ainda falta verificar o `\d`:

    ```
    ,.*,\d
       ↑
       regex verificou até aqui (a segunda vírgula)

    a,b,c,123,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vxw,yz
                                         ↑
                       ela já consumiu a string até este ponto
    ```
- Mas como depois da vírgula tem o "y", que não corresponde a `\d`, então ela precisa voltar novamente
- Então ela volta para o "w", depois para o "x", para o "v", e encontra outra vírgula (a que está antes do "v") - no [link de *debug* do regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3Zg6cy/2/debugger), este é o passo 12
- Aí ela vê se depois desta vírgula tem um dígito. Mas como tem a letra "v" (que não corresponde a `\d`), ela volta novamente (para o "u", "t", "s", encontra outra vírgula, verifica se depois tem `\d`, etc...)

Este vai e vem é repetido várias vezes, até que ela finalmente encontra a vírgula antes do "1", e vê que depois dela tem o `1`, que corresponde a `\d`, e finalmente encontra o *match*, que é `,b,c,1`.

---

Já se [*debugarmos* a regex com o quantificador *lazy*](https://regex101.com/r/nJFbDN/2/debugger), veremos porque ela faz em menos passos:

- A regex vai avançando na string até encontrar a primeira vírgula (no caso, é a que está logo depois do "a")
- Como `.*?` é preguiçoso/não-guloso, primeiro ele tenta a menor quantidade possível, que no caso é zero (pois o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências"). Ou seja, ele vê se depois da primeira vírgula tem "zero caracteres seguido de vírgula". Mas como depois da primeira vírgula tem um "b", então ela consome esse "b" (ou seja, ele passa a "fazer parte" do `.*?`) e vê o que tem depois
- Depois do "b" tem uma vírgula, então a regex verifica se depois tem um `\d`. Mas como não tem, o `.*?` passa a considerar todo o trecho "b,c". Então a regex vê que depois disso tem uma vírgula e um `\d` e encontra o *match* `,b,c,1`

---

Fazendo um teste básico em Python, com o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html):

```py
from timeit import timeit
import re

# executa 1 milhão de vezes cada teste
params = { 'number': 1000000, 'globals': globals() }

s = 'a,b,c,123,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vxw,yz'
greedy = re.compile(r',.*,\d')
lazy = re.compile(r',.*?,\d')

print(timeit('greedy.search(s)', **params))
print(timeit('lazy.search(s)', **params))
```

O tempo exato pode variar dependendo do *hardware*, etc, mas de forma geral, a regex gulosa demorou mais (na minha máquina, foi entre 60% a 70% mais demorada), e no [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ekAfF3) e no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/SpecificFarflungCommas#main.py) os resultados foram similares.

Com JavaScript, [a regex *lazy* também se mostrou mais rápida](https://jsbench.me/ulkhnb5qp1/1).

#### Enfim, "*ser mais rápido*" não tem nada a ver com a regex ser gulosa ou não, e sim com a expressão e a string sendo verificada.

Basta mudar a string do exemplo acima para, por exemplo, `a,b,c,x23,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vxw,1z`, que a regex gulosa se torna mais rápida. Isso acontece por causa da forma como o *match* é feito: na regex gulosa, já vimos que ela vai até o fim da string, e depois começa a voltar até encontrar um *match*, enquanto a *lazy* parte do início da string e vai avançando aos poucos até encontrar um *match*.

Então se o *match* estiver mais próximo do início da string, a regex *lazy* encontrará mais rápido, mas se o *match* estiver mais próximo do final da string, a regex gulosa é que será mais rápida (veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/FRiP1A/2) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/FRiP1A/3) como a situação se inverte se mudarmos a string).

---

Enfim, é importante entender as diferenças de funcionamento, em vez de confiar cegamente que o quantificador guloso sempre será mais rápido. Há casos e casos, e como já explicaram nas outras respostas, até mesmo o *match* encontrado pode ser diferente.

Dependendo da *engine*/linguagem/ferramenta, também podem ser feitas otimizações internas que dependem das circunstâncias (tanto da expressão quanto da string sendo verificada), que pode ou não influenciar na quantidade de passos necessários.

Answer (score 2):

Embora essa pergunta foi feita há vários anos atrás, existem alguns equívocos que precisam ser corrigidos.

O `*` não é o único quantificador guloso.
Os quantificadores gulosos são: **`?` `+` `{}` `*`**
Por exemplo, o opcional `?` casa 0 ou 1 vez o elemento anterior.

```
Texto      ER         Casou
aa         ...?       aa
aaa        ...?       aaa
```

Veja que no segundo texto a ER casou com ***aaa*** em vez de ***aa***.
Quantificadores gulosos sempre casarão com o máximo que ele puder.
No primeiro texto a ER casou com ***aa*** apenas porque não havia um terceiro caractere.

Já o `{}` só não é guloso se você o usar na forma `{numero}`.
Como em `{3}`. Nesse caso ele é exato. 
Nas outra formas ele também é guloso.

Os quantificadores não-gulosos são: **`??` `*?` `+?` `{}?`**
Ou seja, os quantificadores gulosos "colados" com uma `?` à sua direita.
Ao contrário dos gulosos, eles sempre casam com o mínimo possível.

```
Texto      ER         Casou
aa         ...??      aa
aaa        ...??      aa
```

Observe que embora o segundo texto seja maior, a ER ainda casou com ***aa***.
Porquê? Porque o `??` não é guloso. Ele casou com o mínimo possível.

Um quantificador não-guloso mostra sua verdadeira utilidade quando há um elemento à sua direita.
ele vai casando com os caracteres do texto, respeitando a quantidade máxima, até encontrar um caractere que também casa com o elemento à sua direita.
nesse caso, ele, como um metacaractere cavalheiro, cede o caractere para seu vizinho, que então casa com esse caractere.

Já o guloso vai casando com tudo que ele pode, respeitando a quantidade máxima, até ele não ter mais nada para casar. Então o fominha olha para sua direita, só para ver seu vizinho o encarando feio. Sob livre e espontânea pressão, ele vai descasando caracteres, um por um, da direita para esquerda, até encontrar o caractere que o seu vizinho ranzinza quer casar, cedendo esse caractere para ele.

Embora a descrição diz "caractere" no singular, o elemento vizinho não necessariamente precisa casar com só um caractere. Ele poderia ser o metacaractere grupo `()`, agrupando vários metacaracteres representantes e caracteres literais e/ou ele ser seguido de um quantificador, podendo assim, representar mais de um caractere.

Para demonstrar, veja duas ER aplicadas no código html abaixo:

<b>negrito</b>
<p>parágrafo</p>
<strong>importante</strong>
<h1>título</h1>

Com a ER `<.*>`:

`<b>negrito</b>`
`<p>parágrafo</p>`
`<strong>importante</strong>`
`<h1>título</h1>`

E com a ER `<.*?>`:

`<b>`negrito`</b>`
`<p>`parágrafo`</p>`
`<strong>`importante`</strong>`
`<h1>`título`</h1>`

A parte destacada e em negrito é o que a ER casou.
Observe como a ER com o quantificador `*` casou tudo do primeiro sinal de menor(<) até o último sinal de maior(>).
Enquanto a ER com o `*?` só casou com as tags html.