# O fim de uma captura em uma expressão regular

Tags: php, regex

Eu não sei que título poderia ficar melhor do que esse, pois não entendo muito bem de termos técnicos relacionados à expressão regular.

Mas vou descrever o meu problema. Tenho um código, onde eu gero uma expressão regulara para poder capturar determinada expressão e, em seguida, tranforma-a em um código php válido.

Por exemplo, a string a seguir:

```
%[ $variable = 1 ]
```

gera o seguinte código:

```
<?php $variable = 1; ?>
```

Consigo fazer isso funcionar. Se colocar expressões como essa abaixo funcione corretamente:

```
 %[ foreach ($array as $key => $value) ]
 %[ endforeach ]
```

Só que eu estou tendo problemas quandos a expressão capturada está na mesma linha.

Um exemplo:

```
[% echo "Esse é o Wallace"] [% "esse é meu nome" ]
```

A saída gera isso:

```
 <?php echo "Esse é o Wallace" ][% "esse é meu nome ?>
```

A expressão regular que uso para fazer isso é gerada por uma classe que monta ela da seguinte forma (baseando-me no sprintf, para melhorar a visualização)

```
$exp1 = '%[';

$exp2 = ']';

$regexp = sprintf('/%s\s*(.*)\s*%s/', preg_quote($exp1), preg_quote($exp2));

preg_replace($regexp, '<?php $1 ?>', $meu_codigo_aqui);
```

Que seria a expressão:

```
 '/%\[\s*(.*)\s*\]/'
```

É compreensível que no caso onde houve o resultado não esperado a expressão reconhece apenas o último `]` como sendo o final.

Porém o que desejo é que essa mesma expressão regular me retorne os dados da seguinte forma:

```
 %[ echo "Expressão 1"] %[echo "Expressão 2"]

 <?php echo "Expressão 1" ?> <?php "Expressão 2" ?>
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Gostaria que, quando minha expressão terminar com `]` e tiver outra começando com `%[`, esses dois grupos não se misturem, mas que cada um seja interpretado separadamente.

Comment: Warning: a variável que recebe o `sprintf()` está difirente da que passada para `preg_replace()` faltou um `e` :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É simples e você [ja fez um pergunta sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94094/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-express%C3%A3o-regular-gulosa/94104#94104) :

Altere para :

```
 '/%\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]/'
```

O Operador não guloso.

#### Adendo

Cuidado ao utilizar [o operado `\s`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110701/o-que-significa-o-atalho-s-nas-regex), muitas pessoas o usam achando que ele significa apenas o caractere `' '`(espaço). Você pode acabar capturando coisas a mais que não deseja.

Você também havia comentado sobre o modificador `s` para que a expressão regular considere linha por linha. Contudo este não esta correto. O modificador de linha por linha é o `m`.

- **`s`** = simple line. Ele vai considerar apenas a primeira linha, e as demais serão ignoradas.
- **`m`** = multi line. Este sim ira considera cada linha nova como uma nova sentença.

Em relação ao REGEX no PHP tente alterar o modificador de inicio/fim `/`, pois caso seja necessário capturar um `/` literal sera necessário escapá-la.

- `/http:\/\//`, foi necessário escapar o `/`, pois o PHP poderia ter considerado como termino da regex. o que geraria erro.
- `~http://~`, não foi necessario escapar `/` pois o modificador de inicio/fim é o `~`.

Geralmente eu uso o `~`, pois não se tenta capturá-lo, mas vale lembrar que esta pode ser qualquer caractere não alfanumérico `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.