# Expressão regular com terminação especifica trazer 3 primeiros caracteres

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Estou tentando faz uma expressão regular no Oracle com o seguinte requisito:

- Terminar com uma letra especifica, caso tenha essa letra no meio não buscar.
- Retornar os 3 primeiros dígitos da string.

Para resolver o primeiro problema posso usar:

```
a\b
```

O "a" sendo a letra, o `\b` para pegar uma posição de borda após a letra.

Para resolver o segundo problema, ou seja, retornar os 3 primeiros digitos:

```
^(...){1,1}
```

Agora como faço para juntar as duas condições? Ou o jeito que estou fazendo não daria certo?

Exemplos, que terminam como a letra "a", e preciso que retorne os 3 primeiros:

> **anh**anguera
>   **pro**blema
>   **per**gunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estava pensando em uma unica expressão, mas não preciso, pois preciso filtrar todos que termine com a letra que quero, e mostrar os 3 primeiros caracteres, ficando assim o script:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(t.string,'^(...){1,1}')
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE regexp_like(t.string,'A$')
```

Tiver que mudar o `a\b` para `A$`, pois o Oracle não reconhece. Dicas e sugestões são sempre bem vindas.

Utilizei a documentação para me ajudar:
[Using Regular Expressions With Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)

Comment: OBS.: `{1,1}` não esta fazendo nada, pois por *default* ele vai capturar 1 vez, e como sua repetição esta limitado a mínimo 1 máximo 1, o efeito é o mesmo ficando apenas `^(...)` [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/RoQE1n/1)

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme

Answer (score 1):

A abstração que você mostrou em sua própria resposta esta correta, mas vejamos como seria a REGEX por completo.

`(\S{3})\S*?m\b`

#### Explicação

Eu posso dividir essa REGEX em 3 partes :

- `(\S{3})` - Captura 3 caracteres, que não sejam de espaçamento. [veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110701/14213).
- `\S*?` - Captura infinitos caracteres, que não sejam de espaçamento, mas o mínimo necessário. [veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94094/14213).
- `m\b` - Como você mesmo disse, delimita a fronteira.

[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/RoQE1n/2)

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, a expressão no [regex101](http://www.regex101.com) mostra no lado direito o primeiro grupo e o full match,  no [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) retorna o full match.

Comment: @David os links estão com valores padrões, teria de salvar o para lincar, o regex101 basta apertar `ctrl+s`.  Sobre a questão de não mostrar o grupo, pode ser da ferramenta.