# REGEX - Como capturar blocos de CASE WHEN ... END

Tags: java, regex

Bom dia, pessoal.

Estou tentando fazer um regex pra capturar blocos de CASE WHEN ... END. De modo que desse string:

```
iduser + CaSe  WhEn ("end") = 0 THEN 'CASE WHEN' ELSE '  END ' END + sum(iduser ) + CASE  WHEN LANGUAGE = 3 THEN 4 ELSE 5 END
```

Sejam capturados os blocos:

```
CaSe  WhEn ("end") = 0 THEN 'CASE WHEN' ELSE 'END' END
CASE  WHEN LANGUAGE = 3 THEN 4 ELSE 5 END
```

O que eu consigo até agora, foi fruto de um regex que eu havia feito com muito suor para pegar string entre colchetes, está assim:

```
(CASE\\s*WHEN)([^)]+)(END)
```

Porém, existem alguns problemas:

- `([^)]+)` -> Essa parte não faz sentido pra mim, mas sem ela, não
  funciona;
- Não quero que o regex capture blocos entre aspas (simples
  ou duplas).
- `([^)]+)` -> Além de não fazer sentido, ela faz com que string com parênteses não funcionem.

EDIT

O regex está assim agora, consegui evoluir um pouco:

```
(?i)(CASE\s*WHEN)(\s*.*)(END)
```

Agora não tem mais o parênteses sem sentido e está case insensitive. Mas, ainda não está ignorando as aspas. E essa modificação fez parar de pegar todos os blocos e está juntando todos em um.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Pode ser com Java ou tem que ser com regex mesmo?

Comment: Pode ser Java. Mas gostaria muito de usar regex nessa solução.

Comment: poderia posta um seu código com as aspas que esta sendo ignoradas ?

Comment: Ex: CASE  WHEN LANGUAGE = 0 THEN 'end' ELSE 'case when' END. O regex deve ignorar os termos entre aspas simples E duplas.

Comment: Edita a pergunta e coloca a String "verdadeira".

Comment: Como assim string "verdadeira"?

Comment: A String de exemplo não tem nenhuma aspa

Comment: Coloca as variações de case tb

Comment: Editei. Mas esse problema está escrito no corpo da pergunta. É importante ler tudo antes, pra compreender o problema como um todo.

Comment: Até existe [uma solução com regex](https://regex101.com/r/3Jmyhl/1/), mas há 2 poréns: ela usa recursos que o Java não suporta, e acho que não é a ferramenta adequada para este problema. Talvez a solução passe por usar algo como o [antlr](https://www.antlr.org/), por exemplo

Answer (score 0):

O problema principal é o "end" pois ele seria o delimitador de fim. E como você tem "end" no meio da *string* não é possível fazer simplesmente

```
(?i)(CASE\s+WHEN.*?END)
```

pois a [captura fica incorreta](https://regex101.com/r/1YykP3/1).

Para isso temos que analisar o que este "end" do meio tem de diferente do final, que é simples a aspa.

#### Solução final

```
(?i)(CASE\s+WHEN.*?(?<!['"])END)
```

#### Explicação

- `(?i)` - torna a pesquisa case insencitive.
- `CASE\s+WHEN` busca a sentença `CASE WHEN` com no mínimo um espaço.
- `.*?` - captura tudo, mas tenta o menor possível. [Operador não guloso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94104/14213)
- `(?<!['"])` - é um *negative-lookahead* que verifica o carácter anterior a `END`, e este nao pode ser aspa simlples ou dupla.
- `END` - Busca Literal por `END`.

[Veja funcionado](https://regex101.com/r/1YykP3/2)

Comment: Guilherme, muito obrigado. Mas não funcionou tão bem. Sua solução funciona apenas se o 'end' entre aspas estiver sozinho. Se colocar um espaço ' end' já não funciona mais.

Estudando os operadores, consegui chegar nessa solução, que funciona pior que a sua:
(?i)(CASE\s*WHEN)(\s*.*?[^\'\"])(END)