# Expressão regular para remover imagens que contenham um range de altura no estilo inline

Tags: php, regex

Como eu poderia melhorar essa expressão regular para remover imagens que tenham range de 29 a 45: `[0-9]{29, 45}`?

minha expressão:

```
<img.+?(style=\".+?height:(29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45)%;.+?\")[^>]*>
```

Quando tentei fazer assim ele removeu o estilo da imagem e não a imagem em si:

```
 <img.+?(style=\".+?height:([0-9]{29, 45})%;.+?\")[^>]*>
```

Veja o meu exemplo:

**https://regexr.com/3h5b5**

Comment: Coloque um inline cru, para ver.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o seu intervalo é de 29 a 45 ou seja ele é relativamente regular, a logica seria a seguinte :

- Separar os decimais e unidades
- Verificar qual é o *rang* de cada um deles
- Decimal : `[2-4]`, unidade : `[0-9]` => `\d`

Contudo a exceção que é do 29 e 45, assim :

- Decimal 2, unidade 9.
- Decimal 4 tem unidade de `[0-5]`

Então a regra ficaria :

```
29|3\d|4[0-5]
```

E REGEX completa :

```
<img.+?(style=\".+?height:(29|3\d|4[0-5])%;.+?\")[^>]*>
```

#### Quanto ao `{29, 45}`

Isso na verdade é um intervalo de repetição e não numero permitidos, para mias detalhes pode ver [Quantificadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94104/14213)

Comment: Valeu, perfeito.

Comment: `3\d` é o mesmo que `3[0-9]` ?

Comment: @Articuno exatamente.

Comment: @MagicHat Não esta na questão, mas pode ser posto

Comment: @MagicHat mas pela REGEX original, pode ser que ele queira capturar apenas as que são em `%`

Comment: @MagicHat Exatamente :D

Comment: O `.+?` poderia casar de uma imagem válida até a próxima imagem inválida. Exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/BiB8Xn/1. Pode usar `[^"]*?` ou [DOM](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dom.php).

Comment: @Mariano eu fiz os teste e na verdade o ideal seria trocar todos os `.+?` por `[^>]+?` pois ai você estaria limitando o inicio e fim corretamente `<img` ate `>`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/BiB8Xn/2

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Essa é outra opção, ou `[^>]*?` por fora do *style* e `[^"]*?` dentro do *style*. Lembre-se de que um `>` pode aparecer entre aspas em um *style*. Mas eu recomendaria repetir com `*` em vez de `+`. De qualquer forma, o DOM é a única opção segura aqui. Há sempre outra exceção que quebraria o regex ao analisar html.

Comment: @Mariano exato, se ficar complexo d+ o ideal é usar um parser