# Como evitar greedy repetition (.*) para buscar string que possui inicio definido, meio dinâmico e fim definido?

Tags: regex

Tenho um arquivo de log que é alvo de busca via uso da regex `^WebServer:.*endOfLine`. Considerando o log abaixo essa regex está gerando 485 iterações (steps):

String:

```
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...step1 endOfLine
WebServerClosed: status 10. S
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...step1 endOfLine
WebServerClosed: status 10. S
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...step1 endOfLine
WebServerClosed: status 10. S
WebServer: error 2312. Falha de conexão com o destino. StartLine Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...step1 endOfLine
WebServerClosed: status 10. Sent Request
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...step1 endOfLine
WebServerClosed: status 10. S
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...step1 endOfLine
WebServerClosed: status 10. S
```

O resultado da captura promovida pela regex é:

```
WebServer: error 2312. Falha de conexão com o destino. StartLine Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...step1 endOfLine
```

**Considerando o mesmo produto final, que abordagem/técnica possui utilizar para gerar menos iterações e o uso do `.*` (greedy repetition)?**

Estou utilizando o: https://regex101.com

Comment: Em qual site/linguagem/ferramenta vc testou? No regex101, por exemplo, só deu 109 steps: https://regex101.com/r/qEI5Lz/1/ (e a versão não-greedy fica pior, leva mais de 290: https://regex101.com/r/qEI5Lz/2/) - e dependendo da linguagem/ferramenta/engine, a quantidade pode variar tb, por isso é interessante colocar qual vc está usando e como está medindo

Comment: @hkotsubo sim, lá na função de Regex Debugger

Comment: Ah tá, é que no *debugger* ele conta os passos desde o início, mas na tela principal acho que ele só conta a partir da linha, por isso deu menos...

Comment: De qualquer forma, não acho que tenha como deixar muito mais rápida, e usar o quantificador *lazy*, conforme resposta abaixo, na verdade deixa mais lento...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para deixar o quantificador não-*greedy* (também chamado de *lazy*, mais informações [aqui](/q/415757/112052) e [aqui](/a/401755/112052)), bastaria trocar a regex para `^WebServer:.*?endOfLine` - o `?` logo depois do `*` torna-o não-*greedy*.

Só que neste caso a regex fica mais lenta: [a sua versão precisa de 485 passos](https://regex101.com/r/qEI5Lz/1/debugger), e a versão *lazy* [precisa de mais de 660 passos](https://regex101.com/r/qEI5Lz/2/debugger).

Conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482807/112052), o fato de ser ou não *greedy* não necessariamente torna a regex mais lenta ou mais rápida, pois isso depende da expressão **e** da string sendo verificada.

Neste caso eu diria que o mais indicado parece ser o quantificador *greedy* mesmo. Como o ponto, por padrão, [não considera quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), então `.*` já avança até o final da linha de uma vez. E depois ele vai voltando para verificar se tem `endOfLine`, mas como são poucos passos, ela é mais eficiente do que o *lazy* (que vai testando todos os caracteres após o `:`, até encontrar o `endOfLine`, e como tem muito mais caracteres antes do que depois do `endOfLine`, a versão *greedy* acaba encontrando o *match* em menos passos).

Comment: Show. Quanto ao uso de regex não conheço muito. Estava buscando uma forma de obter o mesmo resultado com a menor quantidade de steps possível pois o conjunto de dados iterado é gigantesco.

Comment: @FábioJânio Então nesse caso talvez regex não seja a melhor opção :-) Se usar alguma linguagem qualquer e um programa que lê linha a linha, vendo se ela começa com "Webserver" e termina com "endOfLine", provavelmente será mais rápido que regex (a maioria das linguagens possui funções como `startsWith` e `endsWith` ou similares, todas geralmente mais rápidas que uma regex)

Answer (score -1):

adiciona um `?` depois do `*` pra que ele deixe de ser greedy.