# Como fazer um regex para selecionar um determinado intervalo de linhas e sempre selecionar o primeiro resultado repetido caso houver?

Tags: java, regex

Como fazer um regex para selecionar linhas inteiras até atingir um valor específico no limite de 5 linhas para baixo? Se o valor for mais de 6 linhas abaixo, então eu não devo selecionar.

Configuração da minha regex:

```
Multiline
Global
```

Essa regex funciona muito bem, ela seleciona do `start` até o valor encontrado dentro do intervalo de 5 linhas. Porém o defeito dela é que se existir mais de um `value1`, ela sempre vai selecionar o último `value1` repetido, entende?

```
^start(?:.*\R){0,5}.*?(value1)
```

Os dados que estou utilizando

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
start
line 1
line 2 value1
line 3 value1
line 4 value1
line 5 value2
line 6
```

Perceba acima que existem 3x `value1`, a regex que mostrei acima sempre vai selecionar o `value1` da line 4 porque esse é o ultimo `value1` dentro do intervalo de 5 linhas.

O esperado é sempre selecionar o primeiro valor repetido se houver. Nesse caso deveria selecionar o `value1` da line 2

Vc pode me ajudar a fazer essa regex?

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar um `?` depois do quantificador `{0,5}`

```
^start(?:.*\R){0,5}?.*?(value1)
                   ^
                  aqui
```

Por padrão, os [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) são "gulosos"/"gananciosos" (também chamados de *greedy*), pois tentam pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres. No caso, `{0,5}` significa "de zero a cinco ocorrências", então ela vai pegar o máximo que conseguir (se conseguir 5, pega, senão tenta com 4, senão com 3, e assim por diante, até encontrar um *match*). Por isso ela acaba pegando a última ocorrência de `value1`.

Ao colocar o `?` na frente do `{0,5}`, ele se torna [*lazy*](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy) ("preguiçoso"), ou seja, pega a menor quantidade possível de caracteres. Com isso, ele pega a primeira ocorrência de `value1` que encontrar.

Entenda melhor como o quantificador *lazy* funciona e suas diferenças para o *greedy* lendo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482807/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/487180/112052).

Então seria algo assim:

```java
String texto = "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n"
        + "start\n"
        + "line 1\n"
        + "line 2 value1\n"
        + "line 3 value1\n"
        + "line 4 value1\n"
        + "line 5 value2\n"
        + "line 6 value1";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^start(?:.*\\R){0,5}?(^.*?value1)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("encontrado: " + matcher.group(1)); // line 2 value1
} else {
    System.out.println("não encontrado");
}
```

Eu troquei os parênteses para pegar a linha inteira que contém o "value1", e depois pego esta linha com o método `group`, assim o resultado é "line 2 value1".

Vale lembrar que se a linha tivesse "value12", a regex pegaria somente até o "value1", deixando o "2" de fora. Tem que ver se é isso que precisa.

---

## Sem regex

Vale mencionar que dá para resolver sem regex, bastando iterar pelas linhas:

```java
String texto = "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n"
        + "start\n"
        + "line 1\n"
        + "line 2 value1\n"
        + "line 3 value1\n"
        + "line 4 value1\n"
        + "line 5 value2\n"
        + "line 6 value1";
int cont = -1;
String valor = null;
for (String linha : texto.split("\n")) {
    if ("start".equals(linha)) {
        cont = 0; // encontrou linha com "start", começa a contagem
    } else if (cont > 0 && cont <= 5 && linha.contains("value1")) {
        valor = linha;
        break; // já encontrei, não precisa ler as outras linhas
    }
    // só atualiza o contador se já encontrou um "start" antes
    // isso é para evitar casos em que há um "value1" antes de ter a linha com "start"
    if (cont >= 0) {
        cont++;
    }
}
if (valor == null) {
    System.out.println("valor não encontrado");
} else {
    System.out.println("encontrado: " + valor);
}
```

Ou seja, quando encontrar a linha com "start", eu começo a contagem. Se encontrar um "value1" e não passou de 5 linhas depois do "start", eu paro.

Não ficou claro se a linha com "start" tem exatamente esse texto e nada mais, ou se ela só começa com "start" - se for esse o caso, bastaria trocar `"start".equals(linha)` por `linha.startsWith("start")`.

E no exemplo acima eu quebro a string em linhas, fazendo o `split`. Mas não ficou claro de onde vem a string. Por exemplo, se está lendo de um arquivo, bastaria [lê-lo linha a linha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868528), o restante da lógica não muda.

Apesar de parecer que faz mais coisas (só porque "tem mais linhas"), na verdade fica mais rápido (fiz testes com o [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh), e a regex foi mais lenta). Isso acontece porque regex tem uma complexidade por trás dos panos que não fica aparente nas poucas linhas de código (por exemplo, e expressão tem que ser compilada - é isso mesmo, **compilada** - gerando uma estrutura interna bem complexa para buscar os *matches*).

Claro que para poucas strings a diferença será imperceptível, mas caso vá processar muitas linhas, pode fazer diferença. Regex pode parecer legal, mas nem sempre é a melhor solução.

---

Por fim, as soluções acima só encontram a primeira ocorrência. Mas caso o texto tenha várias vezes esse padrão *"start + linhas que tem value1"* e você quer encontrar todos, basta adaptar para criar uma lista com todas as ocorrências. Sem regex seria assim:

```java
int cont = -1;
List<String> valores = new ArrayList<>();
for (String linha : texto.split("\n")) {
    if (linha.startsWith("start")) {
        cont = 0; // encontrou linha com "start", começa a contagem
    } else if (cont > 0 && cont <= 5 && linha.contains("value1")) {
        valores.add(linha);
        cont = -1; // já encontrou, reseta o contador (só volta a ser zero se encontrar outro "start")
    }
    if (cont >= 0) {
        cont++;
    }
}
```

E com regex:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^start(?:.*\\R){0,5}?(^.*?value1)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);
List<String> valores = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    valores.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

No final, a lista `valores` terá todas as linhas que satisfazem ao critério (contém "value1" e está até 5 linhas depois do "start").