# Encontrar conteúdo entre 2 strings dentro de uma string gigante com RegExp

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Preciso criar uma função que receba o número do quadro e tire seu conteúdo de um arquivo .txt com mais de 3000 linhas.

Todo quadro tem a seguinte configuração:
Começa com "Quadro X" e termina com "Fonte: (alguma fonte)"

```
Quadro 30–Tabela de tipo de demandante
Tabela de Tipo do Demandante
Código
Descrição da categoria
1Operadora
2Prestador de serviço
3Consumidor
4Gestor
5ANS
Fonte: Elaborado pelos autores.
```

Isso foi o que consegui fazer até agora:

```
const getBoardContent = (board) => {
  fs.readFile("return.txt", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    
    const text = String(data)
    
    const boardContent = text.match(/quadro \d+([\w\s]*)fonte:.*/gim);
    console.log(boardContent)
  }
}
```

O problema é que sempre retorna `null`, mas se por exemplo, eu der match em `/Quadro \d+/gim` ele encontra todos os quadros e se eu der match em `/Fonte: /gim` ele também encontra todas as fontes.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que depois de "quadro" e do número, tem um `–`. Mas na sua regex você usou `[\w\s]`, sendo que o `\w` é [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) que representa um caractere alfa-numérico (uma letra, número ou `_`) e o `\s` corresponde a [espaços e quebras de linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052). Nenhum deles corresponde ao `–`, por isso ela não encontra um *match*.

Se a ideia é pegar "qualquer coisa", incluindo quebras de linha, uma alternativa é:

```
fs.readFile("return.txt", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    const boardContent = data.match(/^quadro \d+[\s\S]*?^fonte:.*$/gim);
    console.log(boardContent);
});
```

Como você usou a [*flag* `m`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags), então os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que normalmente indicam somente o início e fim da string, também passam a indicar o início e fim de uma linha. Fiz assim para garantir que pego as linhas que começam com "quadro" e "fonte".

No meio delas eu uso `[\s\S]`, que basicamente é o `\s` (espaços e quebras de linha) e `\S` (tudo que não é `\s`). Ou seja, pega qualquer tipo de caractere. O [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*?` garante que vou pegar a menor quantidade possível de caracteres, assim ele para quando encontrar uma linha que comece com "fonte" (sobre o comportamento do `*?`, tem mais informações [aqui](/q/415757/112052), [aqui](/a/401755/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482807/112052)).

---

Mas você disse que vai receber o número do quadro e só extrair o conteúdo deste. Então você pode extrair o número da regex e só adicionar nos resultados se for o número que você quer. Por exemplo, se eu só quiser o quadro 30:

```
fs.readFile("return.txt", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    const boardContent = [];
    for (const match of data.matchAll(/^quadro (\d+)[\s\S]*?^fonte:.*$/gim)) {
        let numeroQuadro = parseInt(match[1]);
        if (numeroQuadro == 30) { // só quero o quadro 30 (aqui você coloca a condição que quiser)
            boardContent.push(match[0]);
        }
    }
    console.log(boardContent);
});
```

Agora o `\d+` está [entre parênteses para formar um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Com isso eu consigo pegar o conteúdo dele com `match[1]`. Se for o número que quero, adiciono nos resultados (usando `match[0]`, que conterá toda a string que foi capturada pela regex).

---

Mas claro que também dá para fazer sem regex. Como você deu a entender que o arquivo é grande, talvez seja melhor lê-lo uma linha por vez, em vez de carregar tudo de uma vez na memória:

- se a linha começar com "Quadro [número do quadro]", você inicia um registro
- vai concatenando até encontrar uma linha que começa com "Fonte:"

Mais ou menos assim:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
var lineReader = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('return.txt', { encoding: 'utf-8' })
});

var contents = [];
var current = '';
var numeroQuadro = 30;
lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  if (line.startsWith(`Quadro ${numeroQuadro}–`)) {
    current = line; // iniciou o conteúdo do quadro
  } else if (current) { // se está no meio do conteúdo do quadro
    if (line.startsWith('Fonte:')) { // verifica se terminou
      // se terminou, adiciona no array de resultados e zera o conteúdo
      contents.push(`${current}\n${line}`);
      current = '';
    } else { // se não terminou, só adiciona ao conteúdo atual
      current += `\n${line}`;
    }
  } 
});

// depois que leu tudo, imprime o conteúdo encontrado
lineReader.on('close', function () {
    console.log('Quadro encontrado: ', contents);
});
```