# Como obter uma string a partir do inicio dela até uma palavra determinada em Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho a seguinte string:

- *fourthWallWidth must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN` (cast from the value `""`).*

Tendo em mente que **fourthWallWidth** é uma string variável que sempre aparecerá no início da string e o restante é fixo, gostaria de obter uma substring a partir do começo da string até **`number`**

O resultado final deveria ser assim:

- *fourthWallWidth must be a `number`*

Comment: pronto! Mas resumindo para você, eu só preciso pegar tudo desde o início da string até o `number`. Isso será implementado em javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A princípio, bastaria pegar tudo do início da string até encontrar o `number` (incluindo as aspas - no caso, o `` ` ``). O fato do fourthWallWidth ser variável - segundo o [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/541133/como-obter-uma-string-a-partir-do-inicio-dela-at%C3%A9-uma-palavra-determinada-em-reg?noredirect=1#comment971907_541133) - não parece ser relevante, já que a ideia é pegar qualquer coisa desde o início:

```js
var texto = 'fourthWallWidth must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN` (cast from the value `""`).';
var match = texto.match(/^.*?`number`/);
if (match) {
    var inicioAteNumber = match[0];
    console.log(inicioAteNumber);
} else {
    console.log('number não encontrado');
}
```

O marcador `^` indica o início da string. Depois `.*` é "zero ou mais caracteres" (qualquer caractere), e o `?` faz com que a busca seja *lazy* (leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94094/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052) para entender melhor, mas a princípio, se tiver várias ocorrências de `number`, esta regex encontrará a primeira).

Repare que incluí os `` ` `` na busca, então eles também estarão no resultado final. Depois eu vejo se a regex encontrou algo. Caso tenha encontrado, `match` será um array no qual o primeiro elemento é o trecho da string que foi encontrado.

Claro que você também poderia deixar mais específico. Como existe uma parte que é fixa, daria para ser algo como:

```js
var texto = 'fourthWallWidth must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN` (cast from the value `""`).';
var match = texto.match(/^\w+ must be a `number`/);
if (match) {
    var inicioAteNumber = match[0];
    console.log(inicioAteNumber);
} else {
    console.log('number não encontrado');
}
```

No caso, agora usei `\w+` (um ou mais caracteres que sejam letras, dígitos ou `_`), o que serve para pegar o trecho "fourthWallWidth" (mas nada impede que se use `.*?` também, só estou sendo mais específico aqui).

---

Mas talvez não precise de regex. Você pode verificar se a string contém `` `number` ``, e caso tenha, pegue a substring que vai do início até o ponto onde ele se encontra:

```js
var texto = 'fourthWallWidth must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN` (cast from the value `""`).';
// posição onde "number" se encontra
var i = texto.indexOf('`number`');
if (i >= 0) {
    // soma 8, porque é a quantidade de caracteres em "number" (incluindo as aspas)
    var inicioAteNumber = texto.substring(0, i + 8);
    console.log(inicioAteNumber);
} else {
    console.log('number não encontrado');
}
```

No caso, [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) retorna a posição onde `number` se encontra (incluindo as `` ` ``), ou `-1` se a string não contém tal trecho. Depois, basta pegar a substring do início até a posição encontrada.

Ou, incluindo a parte fixa (e deixando um pouco mais genérico):

```js
var texto = 'fourthWallWidth must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN` (cast from the value `""`).';
var termoBusca = 'must be a `number`';
// posição onde o termo da busca se encontra
var i = texto.indexOf(termoBusca);
if (i >= 0) {
    var inicioAteNumber = texto.substring(0, i + termoBusca.length);
    console.log(inicioAteNumber);
} else {
    console.log('number não encontrado');
}
```

---

> Fazendo um teste básico, [a solução com `indexOf` se mostrou bem mais rápida](https://jsbench.me/6skyvorjpf/1). Inclusive, também é mais rápido que a solução da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/541141/112052), já que `search`, segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search), internamente converte o argumento para regex (e esse overhead adicional o torna mais lento que `indexOf`).
>
> Claro que para poucas strings pequenas, a diferença é imperceptível, mas de qualquer forma, eu ainda acho `indexOf`/`substring` mais simples e fácil de entender do que regex (mas aí vai de cada um)

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que regex ficaria um resultado muito grande, que pode ser facilmente obtido por:

```js
let str = 'fourthWallWidth must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN` (cast from the value `""`)'
let TermoASerProcurado = '`number`'
let IndexDoTermoASerProcurado = str.search(TermoASerProcurado);
if (IndexDoTermoASerProcurado != -1) {
  let Resultado = str.substring(0, IndexDoTermoASerProcurado + TermoASerProcurado.length);
  console.log(Resultado);
} else {
  console.log('Essa string nao existe na frase inicial.')
}
```

Comment: Corrigindo pelo autor para evitar falso resultado.