# Operador de negação retorna valor que deveria ser descartado

Tags: regex

Ao utilizar o operador de negação, desejo obter somente a parte do texto que não contenha o grupo negado previamente.

Utilizando a expressão `( ?<br\/?> ?)(Unit.)`, eu obtenho o seguinte [resultado](http://regexr.com/3e1br):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao adicionar o operador de negação `?!`, ele nega e ignora, trazendo todos os [resultados](http://regexr.com/3e1bu):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado esperado para a expressão é somente a primeira tag, onde não possui nada anteriormente a palavra **Unit.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua logica esta quase certa, eu digo quase, pois falta uma pequena interpretação.

Em REGEX você deve analisar que ela pode iniciar/terminar onde quiser, a menos que você defina explicitamente como ela deve se comportar.

### Analisando o que ocorre

#### Legenda

- `^` Inicio do texto a ser interpretado
- `$` Fim do texto a ser interpretado

#### Analise 1

```html
<td>Preço<br/>Unit.</td>
^
$
```

Note que nesse caço o texto interpretado so tem `<`, logo a REGEX não bate

#### Analise 2

```html
<td>Preço<br/>Unit.</td>
^      $
```

Note que nesse caço o texto interpretado é `<td>Preç`, logo a REGEX não bate

#### Analise 3

```html
<td>Preço<br/>Unit.</td>
         ^        $
```

Note que nesse caço o texto interpretado é `<br/>Unit.`, se a REGEX for a 1ª
`( ?<br\/?> ?)(Unit.)`, bate perfeitamente achando o resultado, mas como é a 2ª
`(?! ?<br\/?> ?)(Unit.)` o lookback inibe o resultado.

#### Analise 4

```html
<td>Preço<br/>Unit.</td>
              ^   $
```

Note que nesse caço o texto interpretado é `Unit.`, se a REGEX for a 1ª
`( ?<br\/?> ?)(Unit.)`, o resultado não é encontrado, pois falta `?<br\/?> ?`
no inicio, mas como a 2ª `(?! ?<br\/?> ?)(Unit.)`, bate perfeitamente,
pois o lookback diz que não deve conter `?<br\/?> ?` antes de `(Unit.)`,
e não ter nada é valido. Assim retornando como resultado valido.

### Possível solução

Usando a flag `m` para considerar cada nova linha `\n` como um novo texto a ser interpretado. Pode ser alterar a REGEX para :

```
/^(?!.* ?<br\/?> ?Unit\..*)(.*Unit\..*)$/gm
```

[Veja no REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/vJ4mA8/1)

#### Explicação

- `^...$` - Estou dizendo que a sentença a ser analisada é do inicio ao fim.
- `(?!.* ?<br\/?> ?Unit\..*)` - Estou dizendo que se ele achar `.* ?<br\/?> ?Unit\..*` não deve capturar.
- `(.*Unit\..*)` - Conteudo a ser capturado.

### Adendo

- O melhor modo de se pensar o lookback de negação (ao meu ver) é, imaginar a sentença exata do que ele deve capturar.
- Você utilizou `Unit.` no que se você deseja capturar o `.` literal deve escapá-lo, caso contrario a captura aceitara `UnitG`, `Unit#`, `Unit`.

Comment: Entendi, Guilherme. Realmente eu estava imaginando o funcionamento do lookback de maneira incorreta.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, eu tinha ficado preocupado que a explicação não tinha ficado boa, mas que bom que entendeu :D