# Remover nomes duplicados com expressão regular

Tags: r, regex

Suponha que eu tenha o seguinte vetor, com os nomes de presidentes da república:

```
presidentes <- c("da Fonseca, DeodoroDeodoro da Fonseca", 
"Peixoto, FlorianoFloriano Peixoto", "de Morais, PrudentePrudente de Morais", 
"Sales, CamposCampos Sales")
```

Eu gostaria de formatar este vetor de maneira que fosse possível ler diretamente o nome de cada presidente:

```
"Deodoro da Fonseca" "Floriano Peixoto" "Prudente de Morais" "Campos Sales"
```

Imagino que exista alguma expressão regular que faça isto, mas não estou conseguindo construi-la.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assim não é bonito mas funcionou:

```
library(stringr)
rex <- ".*, [:alpha:]{1,}[A-Z]{1}"
nomes_invertidos <- str_extract_all(presidentes, rex) %>% unlist() %>% str_sub(end = -2)
str_replace_all(presidentes, nomes_invertidos, replacement = "")

[1] "Deodoro da Fonseca" "Floriano Peixoto"   "Prudente de Morais" "Campos Sales"
```

A regex pega:

- qualquer coisa até a vírgula (`.*,`),
- a vírgula,
- um espaço,
- quaisquer letras até a primeira letra maiúscula (`[:alpha:]{1,}[A-Z]{1}`) .

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, Daniel. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

A solução pode variar. Utilizei a seguinte:

```
Regex -> ^.+?,\s*(\w+)\1(.+?)$

Substituição -> $1$2
```

Não sei se na linguagem R funciona, mas o trecho da retrorreferência `(\w+)\1` captura apenas o trecho que tem repetição (de apenas um nome) e concatena com o restante do trecho de outra captura.

Testei com o notepad++ e funcionou.

Em R, essa expressão pode ser utilizada da seguinte forma:

```
gsub("^.+?,\\s*(\\w+)\\1(.+?)$", "\\1\\2", presidentes)
#[1] "Deodoro da Fonseca" "Floriano Peixoto"   "Prudente de Morais" "Campos Sales"
```

Comment: Funcionou e ficou bem elegante. Sua regex em R, com o comando `gsub`, ficaria assim: `gsub("^.+?,\\s*(\\w+)\\1(.+?)$", "\\1\\2", presidentes)`. Tomei a liberdade de adicionar à resposta.

Comment: +1 pelo incremento e melhoria da solução pela linguagem. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não compreendo a linguagem `r`, mas como eu já [expliquei aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147601/14213), você pode fazer um busca simples que encontre a mesma sequencia duplicada, e substituir por uma.

- pattern : `([a-z]+)\1`
- replace : `$1`
- flag : `i`, e `g`, caso a linguagem necessite especificar "substituir todos".

REGEX em JS : `str.replace(/([a-z]+)\1/gi, '$1')`

Veja funcionando em [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/jT8dE1/1)

#### Explicação

- `([a-z]+)` - Grupo 1
- `[a-z]` - Esta limitado a letras, e como tem a flag `i` aceita Maiúscula e minuscula.
- `\1` - Retoma a mesma captura do grupo 1. gerando a busca por partes duplicadas.

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub(".*[a-z]([A-Z])", "\\1", p)
```

ou seja:

```
de Morais, PrudentePrudente de Morais
..................eP
                   ↓
                   Prudente de Morais
```

Comment: Fala amigo, beleza? Pode explicar detalhadamente o que o seu código faz?

Answer (score 1):

Sei que já há algumas respostas para está questão e que a pergunta foi feita há anos atrás; mas estava praticando outras formas de tentar fazer isso.

Acabei encontrando o seguinte com `str_replace`:

```
str_replace(presidentes,
            pattern = "(.*, \\w+)([A-Z].*)",
            replacement = "\\2")

[1] "Deodoro da Fonseca" "Floriano Peixoto"   "Prudente de Morais" "Campos Sales"
```

O significado:

- `(.*, \\w+)` - pegue "qualquer coisa, seguida de uma vírgula, seguida de um espaço, seguida de uma palavra" e coloque em um primeiro bloco;
- `([A-Z].*)` - depois do primeiro bloco, pegue "a primeira letra maiúscula seguido de qualquer coisa" e coloque em um segundo bloco

No `replacement = " "` peço para retornar apenas o segundo bloco.