# Dúvida com o switch do Gerador de Analisadores Léxicos e Sintáticos (GALS)

Tags: java, compilação, compiladores, projeto-de-compiladores

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O GALS gera o código em Java. Quero colocá-lo no eclipse para fazer telinha e tal. Me disseram que no método `nextState` da classe `lexico`, tem que colocar um `switch` com uns números. Mas de onde vem esses números?

```
private int nextState(char c, int state)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case 0:
            switch (c)
            {
                case 9: return 1;
                case 10: return 1;
                case 13: return 1;
                case 32: return 1;
                case 33: return 2;
                case 34: return 3;
                case 40: return 4;
                case 41: return 5;
                case 42: return 6;
                case 43: return 7;
                case 44: return 8;
                case 45: return 9;
                case 47: return 10;
                case 48: return 11;
                case 49: return 11;
                case 50: return 11;
                case 51: return 11;
                case 52: return 11;
                case 53: return 11;
                case 54: return 11;
                case 55: return 11;
                case 56: return 11;
                case 57: return 11;
                case 59: return 12;
                case 60: return 13;
                case 61: return 14;
                case 62: return 15;
                case 65: return 16;
                case 66: return 16;
                case 67: return 16;
                case 68: return 16;
                case 69: return 16;
                case 70: return 16;
                case 71: return 16;
                case 72: return 16;
                case 73: return 16;
                case 74: return 16;
                case 75: return 16;
                case 76: return 16;
                case 77: return 16;
                case 78: return 16;
                case 79: return 16;
                case 80: return 16;
                case 81: return 16;
                case 82: return 16;
                case 83: return 16;
                case 84: return 16;
                case 85: return 16;
                case 86: return 16;
                case 87: return 16;
                case 88: return 16;
                case 89: return 16;
                case 90: return 16;
                case 97: return 16;
                case 98: return 16;
                case 99: return 16;
                case 100: return 16;
                case 101: return 16;
                case 102: return 16;
                case 103: return 16;
                case 104: return 16;
                case 105: return 16;
                case 106: return 16;
                case 107: return 16;
                case 108: return 16;
                case 109: return 16;
                case 110: return 16;
                case 111: return 16;
                case 112: return 16;
                case 113: return 16;
                case 114: return 16;
                case 115: return 16;
                case 116: return 16;
                case 117: return 16;
                case 118: return 16;
                case 119: return 16;
                case 120: return 16;
                case 121: return 16;
                case 122: return 16;
                case 123: return 17;
                case 125: return 18;
                default: return -1;
            }
        case 1:
            switch (c)
            {
                case 9: return 1;
                case 10: return 1;
                case 13: return 1;
                case 32: return 1;
                default: return -1;
            }
        case 3:
            switch (c)
            {
                case 9: return 3;
                case 10: return 3;
                case 13: return 3;
                case 32: return 3;
                case 33: return 3;
                case 34: return 19;
                case 35: return 3;
                case 36: return 3;
                case 37: return 3;
                case 38: return 3;
                case 39: return 3;
                case 40: return 3;
                case 41: return 3;
                case 42: return 3;
                case 43: return 3;
                case 44: return 3;
                case 45: return 3;
                case 46: return 3;
                case 47: return 3;
                case 48: return 3;
                case 49: return 3;
                case 50: return 3;
                case 51: return 3;
                case 52: return 3;
                case 53: return 3;
                case 54: return 3;
                case 55: return 3;
                case 56: return 3;
                case 57: return 3;
                case 58: return 3;
                case 59: return 3;
                case 60: return 3;
                case 61: return 3;
                case 62: return 3;
                case 63: return 3;
                case 64: return 3;
                case 65: return 3;
                case 66: return 3;
                case 67: return 3;
                case 68: return 3;
                case 69: return 3;
                case 70: return 3;
                case 71: return 3;
                case 72: return 3;
                case 73: return 3;
                case 74: return 3;
                case 75: return 3;
                case 76: return 3;
                case 77: return 3;
                case 78: return 3;
                case 79: return 3;
                case 80: return 3;
                case 81: return 3;
                case 82: return 3;
                case 83: return 3;
                case 84: return 3;
                case 85: return 3;
                case 86: return 3;
                case 87: return 3;
                case 88: return 3;
                case 89: return 3;
                case 90: return 3;
                case 91: return 3;
                case 92: return 3;
                case 93: return 3;
                case 94: return 3;
                case 95: return 3;
                case 96: return 3;
                case 97: return 3;
                case 98: return 3;
                case 99: return 3;
                case 100: return 3;
                case 101: return 3;
                case 102: return 3;
                case 103: return 3;
                case 104: return 3;
                case 105: return 3;
                case 106: return 3;
                case 107: return 3;
                case 108: return 3;
                case 109: return 3;
                case 110: return 3;
                case 111: return 3;
                case 112: return 3;
                case 113: return 3;
                case 114: return 3;
                case 115: return 3;
                case 116: return 3;
                case 117: return 3;
                case 118: return 3;
                case 119: return 3;
                case 120: return 3;
                case 121: return 3;
                case 122: return 3;
                case 123: return 3;
                case 124: return 3;
                case 125: return 3;
                case 126: return 3;
                case 161: return 3;
                case 162: return 3;
                case 163: return 3;
                case 164: return 3;
                case 165: return 3;
                case 166: return 3;
                case 167: return 3;
                case 168: return 3;
                case 169: return 3;
                case 170: return 3;
                case 171: return 3;
                case 172: return 3;
                case 173: return 3;
                case 174: return 3;
                case 175: return 3;
                case 176: return 3;
                case 177: return 3;
                case 178: return 3;
                case 179: return 3;
                case 180: return 3;
                case 181: return 3;
                case 182: return 3;
                case 183: return 3;
                case 184: return 3;
                case 185: return 3;
                case 186: return 3;
                case 187: return 3;
                case 188: return 3;
                case 189: return 3;
                case 190: return 3;
                case 191: return 3;
                case 192: return 3;
                case 193: return 3;
                case 194: return 3;
                case 195: return 3;
                case 196: return 3;
                case 197: return 3;
                case 198: return 3;
                case 199: return 3;
                case 200: return 3;
                case 201: return 3;
                case 202: return 3;
                case 203: return 3;
                case 204: return 3;
                case 205: return 3;
                case 206: return 3;
                case 207: return 3;
                case 208: return 3;
                case 209: return 3;
                case 210: return 3;
                case 211: return 3;
                case 212: return 3;
                case 213: return 3;
                case 214: return 3;
                case 215: return 3;
                case 216: return 3;
                case 217: return 3;
                case 218: return 3;
                case 219: return 3;
                case 220: return 3;
                case 221: return 3;
                case 222: return 3;
                case 223: return 3;
                case 224: return 3;
                case 225: return 3;
                case 226: return 3;
                case 227: return 3;
                case 228: return 3;
                case 229: return 3;
                case 230: return 3;
                case 231: return 3;
                case 232: return 3;
                case 233: return 3;
                case 234: return 3;
                case 235: return 3;
                case 236: return 3;
                case 237: return 3;
                case 238: return 3;
                case 239: return 3;
                case 240: return 3;
                case 241: return 3;
                case 242: return 3;
                case 243: return 3;
                case 244: return 3;
                case 245: return 3;
                case 246: return 3;
                case 247: return 3;
                case 248: return 3;
                case 249: return 3;
                case 250: return 3;
                case 251: return 3;
                case 252: return 3;
                case 253: return 3;
                case 254: return 3;
                case 255: return 3;
                default: return -1;
            }
        case 10:
            switch (c)
            {
                case 42: return 20;
                default: return -1;
            }
        case 11:
            switch (c)
            {
                case 46: return 21;
                case 48: return 11;
                case 49: return 11;
                case 50: return 11;
                case 51: return 11;
                case 52: return 11;
                case 53: return 11;
                case 54: return 11;
                case 55: return 11;
                case 56: return 11;
                case 57: return 11;
                default: return -1;
            }
        case 13:
            switch (c)
            {
                case 61: return 22;
                case 62: return 23;
                default: return -1;
            }
        case 14:
            switch (c)
            {
                case 61: return 24;
                default: return -1;
            }
        case 15:
            switch (c)
            {
                case 61: return 25;
                default: return -1;
            }
        case 16:
            switch (c)
            {
                case 48: return 26;
                case 49: return 26;
                case 50: return 26;
                case 51: return 26;
                case 52: return 26;
                case 53: return 26;
                case 54: return 26;
                case 55: return 26;
                case 56: return 26;
                case 57: return 26;
                case 65: return 16;
                case 66: return 16;
                case 67: return 16;
                case 68: return 16;
                case 69: return 16;
                case 70: return 16;
                case 71: return 16;
                case 72: return 16;
                case 73: return 16;
                case 74: return 16;
                case 75: return 16;
                case 76: return 16;
                case 77: return 16;
                case 78: return 16;
                case 79: return 16;
                case 80: return 16;
                case 81: return 16;
                case 82: return 16;
                case 83: return 16;
                case 84: return 16;
                case 85: return 16;
                case 86: return 16;
                case 87: return 16;
                case 88: return 16;
                case 89: return 16;
                case 90: return 16;
                case 95: return 16;
                case 97: return 16;
                case 98: return 16;
                case 99: return 16;
                case 100: return 16;
                case 101: return 16;
                case 102: return 16;
                case 103: return 16;
                case 104: return 16;
                case 105: return 16;
                case 106: return 16;
                case 107: return 16;
                case 108: return 16;
                case 109: return 16;
                case 110: return 16;
                case 111: return 16;
                case 112: return 16;
                case 113: return 16;
                case 114: return 16;
                case 115: return 16;
                case 116: return 16;
                case 117: return 16;
                case 118: return 16;
                case 119: return 16;
                case 120: return 16;
                case 121: return 16;
                case 122: return 16;
                default: return -1;
            }
        default: return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gabriella, você está estudando por algum livro de compiladores? Eu tenho o bom e novo livro do dragão aqui, posso pescar uma explicação de lá porque pode ser melhor que a minha, mas se puder falar de onde você está contextualizada, posso tentar uma resposta mais dentro do contexto

Comment: Então... Esse trabalho foi o professor que passou... depois de fazer no GALS, vc tem que gerar o código java para criar uma telinha, e aí a interface vai mostrar se houve um erro lexico ou sintatico. Pelos trabalhos anteriosres que vi do professor, vc tinha que colocar essas numerações no método nextState, mas não sei de onde essa numeração vem. Vc sabe?

Comment: se eu te falar que _vem do autômato de pilha determinístico que está interpretando a entrada_, vou estar falando grego ou aramaico? Ou esse conceito foi bom o suficiente para o que você conhece? Gostaria de dar uma resposta profunda para isso, adoro linguagens formais, mas não tenho disponibilidade agora

Comment: rapaz e como eu faço para obter esses números do autômato de pilha determinístico?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe que a variável `c` é do tipo `char`. Então se utilizarmos caracteres ao invés de números de acordo com os códigos da [tabela ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), teremos o seguinte:

```
private int nextState(char c, int state)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case 0:
            switch (c)
            {
                case '\t': return 1;
                case '\n': return 1;
                case '\r': return 1;
                case ' ': return 1;
                case '!': return 2;
                case '\"': return 3;
                case '(': return 4;
```

Ou seja, esses números são caracteres do texto que o analisador léxico está processando.

Já os números 1, 2, 3 e 4 que tem nos `return`s são estados do seu analisador léxico:

- A análise começa no estado 0.
- Ao encontrar um espaço em branco, quebra de linha ou tab, ele vai ao estado 1.
- Ao encontrar um ponto de exclamação, ele entra no estado 2. Não sei o que isso significa na sua linguagem, mas o estado 2 pode indicar que isso signifique apenas que o operador denotado pelo ponto de exclamação foi encontrado. Pode ser também que o ponto de exclamação indique o começo de um comentário e o estado 2 representaria estar dentro de um comentário. Confira na sua gramática o que significa encontrar-se um ponto de exclamação.
- Ao encontrar uma aspa dupla, ele entra no estado 3, que provavelmente indicaria estar dentro de uma string.
- Ao encontrar o abre-parênteses, ele vai ao estado 4, que significa provavelmente é apenas o estado que indica que um abre-parênteses foi encontrado.

Agora que você postou seu código mais completo, o código que você postou seria equivalente a isso:

```
private int nextState(char c, int state) {
    switch (state) {
        case 0:
            switch (c) {
                case '\t':
                case '\n':
                case '\r':
                case ' ': return 1;
                case '!': return 2;
                case '\"': return 3;
                case '(': return 4;
                case ')': return 5;
                case '*': return 6;
                case '+': return 7;
                case ',': return 8;
                case '-': return 9;
                case '/': return 10;
                case ';': return 12;
                case '<': return 13;
                case '=': return 14;
                case '>': return 15;
                case '{': return 17;
                case '}': return 18;
                default:
                    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return 11;
                    if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') return 16;
                    return -1;
            }
        case 1:
            if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c ==  \r' || c == ' ') return 1;
            return -1;
        case 3:
            if (c == '\"') return 19;
            if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || (c >= ' ' && c <= '~') || (c >= 160 && c <= 255) return 3;
            return -1;
        case 10:
            return c == '*' ? 20 : -1;
        case 11:
            if (c == '.') return 21;
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return 11;
            return -1;
        case 13:
            if (c == '=') return 22;
            if (c == '>') return 23;
            return -1;
        case 14:
            if (c == '=') return 24;
            return -1;
        case 15:
            if (c == '=') return 25;
            return -1;
        case 16:
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return 26;
            if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || c == '_' || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') return 16;
            return -1;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Observando-se esses códigos de estado com base nesta tabela, chegamos a isso:

```
private static final int ESTADO_ERRO = -1;
private static final int ESTADO_INICIAL = 0;
private static final int ESTADO_ESPACO = 1;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_EXCLAMACAO = 2;
private static final int ESTADO_STRING = 3;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_ABRE_PARENTESES = 4;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_FECHA_PARENTESES = 5;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_ASTERISCO = 6;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_MAIS = 7;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_VIRGULA = 8;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_MENOS = 9;
private static final int ESTADO_BARRA = 10;
private static final int ESTADO_NUMERO_INTEIRO = 11;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_PONTO_E_VIRGULA = 12;
private static final int ESTADO_MENOR_QUE = 13;
private static final int ESTADO_IGUAL = 14;
private static final int ESTADO_MAIOR_QUE = 15;
private static final int ESTADO_IDENTIFICADOR = 16;
private static final int ESTADO_ABRE_CHAVES = 17;
private static final int ESTADO_FECHA_CHAVES = 18;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_STRING = 19;
private static final int ESTADO_COMENTARIO_BLOCO = 20;
private static final int ESTADO_NUMERO_PONTO_FLUTUANTE = 21;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_MENOR_OU_IGUAL = 22;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_DIFERENTE = 23;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_IGUAL_IGUAL = 24;
private static final int ESTADO_ACHOU_MAIOR_OU_IGUAL = 25;
private static final int ESTADO_IDENTIFICADOR_COM_NUMEROS = 26;

private int nextState(char c, int state) {
    switch (state) {
        case ESTADO_INICIAL:
            switch (c) {
                case '\t':
                case '\n':
                case '\r':
                case ' ': return ESTADO_ESPACO;
                case '!': return ESTADO_ACHOU_EXCLAMACAO;
                case '\"': return ESTADO_STRING;
                case '(': return ESTADO_ACHOU_ABRE_PARENTESES;
                case ')': return ESTADO_ACHOU_FECHA_PARENTESES;
                case '*': return ESTADO_ACHOU_ASTERISCO;
                case '+': return ESTADO_ACHOU_MAIS;
                case ',': return ESTADO_ACHOU_VIRGULA;
                case '-': return ESTADO_ACHOU_MENOS;
                case '/': return ESTADO_BARRA;
                case ';': return ESTADO_ACHOU_PONTO_E_VIRGULA;
                case '<': return ESTADO_MENOR_QUE;
                case '=': return ESTADO_IGUAL;
                case '>': return ESTADO_MAIOR_QUE;
                case '{': return ESTADO_ABRE_CHAVES;
                case '}': return ESTADO_FECHA_CHAVES;
                default:
                    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return ESTADO_NUMERO_INTEIRO;
                    if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') return ESTADO_IDENTIFICADOR;
                    return ESTADO_ERRO;
            }
        case ESTADO_ESPACO:
            if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c ==  \r' || c == ' ') return ESTADO_ESPACO;
            return ESTADO_ERRO;
        case ESTADO_STRING:
            if (c == '\"') return ESTADO_ACHOU_STRING;
            if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || (c >= ' ' && c <= '~') || (c >= 160 && c <= 255) return ESTADO_STRING;
            return ESTADO_ERRO;
        case ESTADO_BARRA:
            if (c == '*') return ESTADO_COMENTARIO_BLOCO;
            return ESTADO_ERRO;
        case ESTADO_NUMERO_INTEIRO:
            if (c == '.') return 21;
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return ESTADO_NUMERO_INTEIRO;
            return ESTADO_ERRO;
        case ESTADO_MENOR_QUE:
            if (c == '=') return ESTADO_ACHOU_MENOR_OU_IGUAL;
            id (c == '>') return ESTADO_ACHOU_DIFERENTE;
            return ESTADO_ERRO;
        case ESTADO_IGUAL:
            if (c == '=') return ESTADO_ACHOU_IGUAL_IGUAL;
            return ESTADO_ERRO;
        case ESTADO_MAIOR_QUE:
            if (c == '=') return ESTADO_ACHOU_MAIOR_OU_IGUAL;
            return ESTADO_ERRO;
        case ESTADO_IDENTIFICADOR:
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return ESTADO_IDENTIFICADOR_COM_NUMEROS;
            if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || c == '_' || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') return ESTADO_IDENTIFICADOR;
            return ESTADO_ERRO;
        default:
            return ESTADO_ERRO;
    }
}
```

Note que isso ainda parece estar incompleto, pois os comentários iniciados com `/*` não terminam, os números que encontram o ponto decimal não continuam a ser analisados e também não continuam a ser analisados os identificadores que tiverem um número no meio.

Observe que isso daí não é nada mais do que uma forma de implementar a tabela da imagem que você deu, onde o `char c` é a coluna e o `int state` é a linha. O que essa função faz é olhar naquela tabela para responder a seguinte pergunta:

> A partir de um determinado estado quando um determinado caractere estiver na entrada, qual deverá ser o próximo estado?

O -1 parece (mas não tenho certeza) indicar tanto o estado de erro, quanto o estado que indica ao analisador léxico parar, produzir um token como resposta para o analisador sintático, e então reiniciar (no estado 0) em busca do próximo token.

Os caracteres de 32 (espaço) a 126 (til) e de 160 a 255 do estado 3 são caracteres que podem aparecer dentro de uma string, e correspondem aos caracteres imprimíveis da tabela ASCII. A forma como as string são tratadas na sua tabela não permitem sequências de escape para o `"` e nem caracteres Unicode (alfabeto russo, grego, chinês, japonês, árabe, indiano, caracteres acentuados, símbolos matemáticos, emojis, etc).

Comment: Veja, e esses 'cases' quantos eu devo colocar?de onde vem essa quantidade? é da quantidade de caracter que eu defini? e em cada 'case', quantos números eu coloco? de onde vem essa definição?

Comment: @Gabriella, isso é um tanto quanto mais complexo. Veja [máquinas de estados finitos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine?wprov=sfsi1). Infelizmente, compiladores não é um assunto simples; compiladores é uma das aplicações finais do estudo de linguagens formais, teoria dos autômatos, análise sintática, etc. Esses números são os estados do autômato finito, os estados você obtém após transformar a expressão regular em um autômato não determinístico e, então, removendo as transações ambíguas e removendo as transações lambda/transações épsilon.

Comment: Veja [esta resposta sobre autômatos finitos e expressões regulares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165413/64969)

Comment: mas no GALS vc tem como ver isso?

Comment: lá eu fiz a análise lexica e sintática

Comment: tem algo a ver com essa imagem que o GALS gera?

Comment: @Gabriella Resposta editada.

Comment: Amigo, essa parte eu entendi. Mas aí quando joguei no eclipse, a classe `ParserConstants` gera uma tabela ENORME. é maior do que o limite de bytes permitido que é 65535. o que fazer nesses casos?

Comment: the code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Comment: @Gabriella Isso é porque no Java, nenhum método pode ultrapassar o tamanho de 65535 bytes quando compilado. As únicas soluções que vejo são (1) abandonar o GALS, (2) reescrever manualmente o código gerado pelo GALS tal como fiz ou (3) fazer gambiarras e malabarismos no código resultante por conta dessa limitação. Para a classe `ParserConstants`, uma possível solução seria dividi-la em várias classes. Tenho um monte de considerações bem negativas acerca da abordagem escolhida pelo GALS de usar `switch`es dentro de `switch`es, e usar um `ParserConstants`, mas isso daí é algo que iria longe.

Comment: É um trabalho de faculdade, tem que ser feito mesmo no GALS... como seria  '' dividi-la em várias classes'' ?

Comment: @Gabriella Coloque metade das constantes em uma classe ou interface `ParserConstants2` e faça `ParserConstants extends ParserConstants2` ou `ParserConstants implements ParserConstants2`. Se não for o suficiente, faça a `ParserConstants3`, `ParserConstants4`, etc. Isso daí é uma gambiarra muito feia e nojenta, mas se você quiser eliminar as gambiarras teria que provavelmente eliminar o GALS por inteiro.

Comment: vou tentar aqui, dividir

Comment: mas na hora de chamar o ` int[] cmd = PARSER_TABLE[state][token-1];` o código vai retornar quaç parser_table? tive que criar 5 ParserConstants!

Comment: @Gabriella Que tal ler essa tabelona de um arquivo ao invés de tê-la diretamente no código-fonte?

Comment: como fazer isso?