# Diferença entre os metacaracteres .* e +

Tags: r, regex

Considere este conjunto de strings:

```
my_names <- c('onda', 'ondas', 'ondass', 'ondassssssss', 'ond', 'on')
```

Usando a linguagem R, verifiquei que os metacaracteres `.*` e `+` trazem a mesma informação:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(my_names, 'ondas.*')
#[1] NA             "ondas"        "ondass"       "ondassssssss" NA            
#[6] NA

str_extract(my_names, 'ondas+')
#[1] NA             "ondas"        "ondass"       "ondassssssss" NA            
#[6] NA
```

Pergunto:

- Qual é a diferença entre os metacaracteres `.*` e `+`?
- Quando eles podem apresentar resultados diferentes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [resposta do @LipESprY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372504/112052) já explica muito bem as diferenças, gostaria apenas de complementar com alguns detalhes.

O primeiro - e talvez eu esteja sendo meio pedante - é que `.*` são **dois** metacaracteres: o ponto (que significa "[qualquer caractere (exceto quebras de linha)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)") e o asterisco, que significa "[zero ou mais ocorrências](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)".

Já o `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências".

Por isso as duas expressões que você usou não são equivalentes. O que aconteceu é que você testou com strings que por acaso dão o mesmo resultado com ambas as regex. Mas isso foi apenas coincidência.

`ondas.*` significa: a palavra "ondas" seguida de zero ou mais caracteres (quaisquer caracteres, exceto quebras de linha). Ou seja, se tiver somente "ondas", serve. Se tiver "ondasabc123 xyz", também serve. E "ondasssss" também serve.

`ondas+` significa: a palavra "onda", seguida de `s+` (uma ou mais ocorrências da letra "s"). Por isso ela serve para "ondas", "ondass" e "ondasssss". Mas ela não serve para "ondasabc123 xyz".

Então um exemplo de caso em que há diferença entre as duas regex é:

```
my_names <- c('ondasabc123 xyz', 'ondassss')

library(stringr)

str_extract(my_names, 'ondas.*')

str_extract(my_names, 'ondas+')
```

A saída é:

```
[1] "ondasabc123 xyz" "ondassss"
[1] "ondas"    "ondassss"
```

Veja que a primeira regex pegou toda a string "ondasabc123 xyz", pois ela de fato corresponde à palavra "ondas" seguida de zero ou mais caracteres (quaisquer caracteres que não sejam quebras de linha). E vale lembrar que o quantificador `*` por padrão é [ganancioso](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) e tenta pegar o maior número possível de caracteres, por isso `.*` pega tudo que puder, até o final da string.

Já a segunda regex só pegou o trecho "ondas" da primeira string, pois é a parte que corresponde à palavra "onda" seguida de uma ou mais letras "s". O restante da string ("abc123 xyz") não corresponde à regex (pois `s+` só pega ocorrências da letra "s"), então essa parte fica de fora do resultado.

Veja este exemplo rodando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/xumjVV).

---

Como já dito, o ponto não considera quebras de linha:

```
my_names <- c('ondasabc\n123', 'ondassss')

library(stringr)

str_extract(my_names, 'ondas.*')
```

Repare que a primeira string possui uma quebra de linha (o `\n`). Por isso o resultado é:

```
[1] "ondasabc" "ondassss"
```

O `.*` pega todos os caracteres depois de "ondas", mas só consegue ir até a quebra de linha, já que por padrão o ponto as desconsidera. Por isso a regex só pega "ondasabc". Veja este exemplo no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/zYdRmF).

---

Como as regex são diferentes, cabe a você escolher aquela que corresponde ao que de fato você precisa. O ideal é que a regex [diga exatamente o que você quer e o que não quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want).

Você quer a palavra "ondas" seguida de qualquer coisa? Então use a primeira opção com `.*`. Você só quer "onda" seguida de uma ou mais letras "s" (e nenhum outro caractere que não seja o "s")? Então use a segunda opção com `s+`.

Você também quer pegar a palavra "onda"? Então pode usar `ondas*` ("onda" seguido de **zero** ou mais letras "s"), ou `ondas?.*` ("onda", seguido de um "s" opcional (o `s?` torna a letra "s" opcional), seguido de "qualquer coisa"). Novamente, a escolha depende do que você quer depois de "onda" ou "ondas": qualquer coisa ou somente letras "s".

Se quer considerar também as quebras de linha, pode usar `ondas(.|\r\n?|\n)*` ([exemplo no Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/CH5rTC)). A expressão dentro de parênteses usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa **ou**) e cobre 3 possibilidades: o ponto (qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha), **ou** `\r\n?` (um [CARRIAGE RETURN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm) (`\r`), seguido de um `\n` opcional - assim consideramos as quebras de linha do MacOS, que é só um `\r`, ou do Windows, que é `\r\n`), **ou** apenas um `\n` (quebras de linha do Unix).

Outra opção para que o ponto considere as quebras de linha é [usar a opção `dotall`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372865/112052) (veja rodando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Hcfz21)):

```
my_names <- c('ondasabc\n123', 'ondassss')

library(stringr)

str_extract(my_names, regex('ondas.*', dotall=TRUE))
```

A diferença, no caso, é que habilitando `dotall`, todos os pontos da regex (caso tenha mais de um ponto em partes diferentes da expressão) serão afetados e passarão a considerar as quebras de linha ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/TbpUVU)). Usando `(.|\r\n?|\n)` (e sem o `dotall` habilitado), apenas esta parte considera as quebras de linha, enquanto os demais pontos (em outras partes da regex) continuam não considerando quebras de linha ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/hktumo)).

---

Enfim, escolha a que melhor se adequar ao que você precisa. As regex não são equivalentes, então avalie se para as strings que você está testando isso faz diferença ou não. Veja se elas pegam o que você precisa, mas também não pegam o que você não precisa (mas avalie também se alguns erros são aceitáveis ou não, e se vale a pena complicar mais a regex para ter mais precisão).

Comment: Olha ele! kkkkkk

Comment: @LipESprY Cheguei um pouco atrasado, mas consegui dar minha contribuição. Agradeço por recomendar minhas respostas, sinal que meus estudos estão dando resultado :-)

Comment: Suas respostas estão dando show em muita documentação. kk

Answer (score 7):

> Qual é a diferença entre os metacaracteres `.*` e `+`?

O asterisco e o mais **são quantificadores**, onde:

- `*` corresponde a **nenhuma ou ilimitadas** ocorrências;
- `+` corresponde a **uma ou ilimitadas** ocorrências;

Já o ponto (`.`), quando fora de uma classe (`[]`), corresponde a qualquer caractere, exceto nova linha. Mas esse comportamento pode variar conforme as *flags* (e/ou linguagem). Quando escapado (`\.`), corresponde ao ponto literal.

Dados os exemplos:

- `ondas.*`

Corresponde à `ondas` seguido de **nenhuma ou ilimitadas ocorrências** de qualquer caractere (`.`), exceto nova linha;

- `ondas+`

Corresponde à `onda` seguido de **uma ou ilimitadas ocorrências** de `s`. Por isso sua expressão encontrou, também, `ondass` e `ondassssssss`. Mas não `onda`. Os quantificadores são relativos à expressão que os antecede. Daí uma das funções dos grupos: `(...)`. Veja um [exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/fVwWnt/2):

Com a expressão `(ondas)+` no texto:

```
onda
ondas
ondass
ondassssssss
ond
on
ondasondasondasondas
```

Serão encontradas **uma ou ilimitadas** ocorrências de `ondas`:

```
onda
'ondas'
'ondas's
'ondas'sssssss
ond
on
'ondasondasondasondas'
```

> Caso queira se aprofundar em RegEx, considere dar uma lida nas [respostas do @hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:112052+[regex]) que estão relacionadas. xD

Comment: Além das minhas respostas - e novamente agradeço por recomendá-las - sugiro olhar a [tag regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) como um todo, principalmente respostas antigas e as mais votadas, pois tem muita coisa interessante, como [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94092/112052) por exemplo :-)

Comment: Ah, esqueci de dizer que a resposta que linkei no comentário anterior não tem nada a ver com a pergunta, é só um exemplo de ótimo conteúdo sobre o assunto :-)