# O que é a "quebra de linha" em uma RegEx?

Tags: r, regex

A linguagem que uso é R.

E, como sugere a teoria de Expressões Regulares, cada linguagem lida de forma diferente com quebras de linhas (`\n`).

Considere a string a seguir:

```
text_1 <- c('Olá, meu nome é Stack OverFlow. Sou um site de programação para
        entusiastas e profissionais')

text_1
[1] "Olá, meu nome é Stack OverFlow. Sou um site de programação para\n            entusiastas e profissionais"
```

Agora, leve em conta o metacaractere ponto (`.`). Segundo a definição, o ponto dá *match* com qualquer caractere, inclusive pontos com **exceção** das quebras de linha.

Mas, a função a seguir pega todo o texto, inclusive o que vem após da quebra (`\n`):

```
library(stringr)

str_extract_all(text_1, 
                regex(pattern = 'f', 
                ignore_case = TRUE, 
                multiline = FALSE))

[[1]]
[1] "F" "f"
```

Eu não entendo o conceito de "quebra de linha". Pelo que li, após a quebra (`\n`) o ponto (`.`) não pegaria mais nada. Mas, mesmo com o argumento `multiline` como `FALSE` e ele pegou o `f` após a quebra (`\n`) da palavra pro`f`issional.

Pergunto:

- O que vem a ser a quebra de linha (`\n`)?
- Como ela funciona na linguagem R?

Comment: O multiline significa que `^` e `$` serão início e fim, consecutivamente, **de cada linha**. Sem o multiline, eles serão início e fim, consecutivamente, de toda a string (texto). Independente se tem quebras de linha ou não. Não faço a mínima ideia de como funcionam as quebras de linha na RegEx do [tag:r]. Vamos aguardar o @hkotsubo pra esclarecer isso (tem que invocá-lo). Kkkkk

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Primeiro vamos ver o que diz a [documentação da função `str_extract_all`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/0.6.2/topics/str_extract_all):

> *Extract All Pieces Of A String That Match A Pattern.*
>
> Extrai todas as partes de uma string que correspondem a um padrão

Pois bem, a regex que você usou tem como padrão a letra `f`:

```
regex(pattern = 'f', ...
```

Um ponto importante a se notar é que **esta regex não possui o metacaractere ponto**. Ela só possui a letra `f`, o que quer dizer que `str_extract_all` vai retornar todas as letras `f` da string. E como a opção `ignore_case` está ativada, ela retorna tanto letras maiúsculas quanto minúsculas. Por isso que o seu código retorna `F` e `f`.

---

Para ver o ponto "em acão", você poderia usar algo como:

```
str_extract_all(text_1, 
                regex(pattern = 'f.*', 
                ignore_case = TRUE, 
                multiline = FALSE))
```

Veja este exemplo rodando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/DEflcA).
Agora a regex é `f.*` (a letra `f` seguida de zero ou mais caracteres). O retorno é:

```
[1] "Flow. Sou um site de programação para"
[2] "fissionais"
```

Como a opção `ignore_case` continua ativada, a regex considera tanto `f` quanto `F`. E o `.*` pega zero ou mais caracteres (qualquer caractere que não seja uma quebra de linha).

A primeira ocorrência começa no `F` e vai até a quebra de linha (logo depois da palavra "para"). E a segunda ocorrência começa no `f` e vai até o final da string (já que não tem mais quebras de linha).

---

Repare que em ambos os casos, a função `str_extract_all` percorre toda a string procurando por algum trecho que corresponde à regex.

A primeira regex é somente a letra `f`, então a regex busca apenas letras `f` ou `F` (já que `ignore_case` está ativado). Ao percorrer a string, tanto faz se ela tem quebras de linha ou não, eu só quero saber se tem algum `f`.

Na segunda regex temos `f.*`, então ela percorre a string procurando por alguma letra `f` mais `.*` (zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere). Só que o ponto não considera as quebras de linha, por isso a regex só pega da letra `f` (ou `F`) até a próxima quebra de linha. Depois que encontra uma ocorrência, a regex continua percorrendo a string para ver se existe algum outro trecho que tem `f` seguido de zero ou mais caracteres (e tanto faz se no meio do caminho ela encontra alguma quebra de linha, o que importa é encontrar algum `f` e depois pegar os caracteres que correspondam a `.*`).

---

Se quiser, [pode usar a opção `dotall`](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringr/man/modifiers.html), que faz com que o ponto corresponda à quebras de linha:

```
str_extract_all(text_1, 
                regex(pattern = 'f.*', 
                ignore_case = TRUE, 
                dotall = TRUE))
```

Veja este exemplo rodando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ztj9Gv). O retorno é:

```
[1] "Flow. Sou um site de programação para\n        entusiastas e profissionais"
```

Pois agora o ponto considera as quebras de linha. Isso significa que a regex `f.*` pega o primeiro `f` (e como `ignore_case` está ativado, o primeiro a ser encontrado é o `F`), e depois pega todos os caracteres (inclusive as quebras de linha) até o final da string.

Só lembrando que [o quantificador `*` é ganancioso](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) e tenta pegar o maior número possível de caracteres que puder. Como agora o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, inclusive quebras de linha, ele acaba indo até o final da string e pegando tudo.

---

Repare que a opção `multiline` não faz diferença neste caso, como já explicado na [resposta do Marcos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372864/112052).

E respondendo à pergunta do título, a quebra de linha é um caractere como qualquer outro. O que muda para uma regex é o significado dela de acordo com determinadas configurações: `ignore_case` muda o significado do `f` (pois passa a considerar também o `F`) e `dotall` muda o significado do ponto (passa a considerar quebras de linha).

Answer (score 10):

> mesmo com o argumento multiline como FALSE e ele pegou o f após a quebra (\n) da palavra profissional.

O argumento `multiline` simplesmente muda o comportamento de `^` e `$` numa expressão regular para que o padrão especificado entre eles comece no início e termine no fim de cada **linha**. Normalmente, eles esperam o padrão do início ao fim de toda a **string**.

Por isso, no seu exemplo a função ainda vai procurar por *matches* do padrão `f` por toda a string, da mesma forma.

Ex. 1: Com `multiline = FALSE`, se tentassemos capturar o padrão `^.*$`, por exemplo, não teríamos qualquer *match* . Isso porque temos um caractere `\n` entre o início e o fim da string, que não condiz com o padrão `.*` do início ao fim da string.

Ex.2: Com `multiline = TRUE`, agora `^.*$` busca por padrões `.*` que começam no início e terminam no fim de cada linha (perceba a diferença para "procurar esse padrão entre o início e fim de cada linha"). Nesse caso, teremos dois *matches*; `Olá, meu nome é Stack OverFlow. Sou um site de programação para` e             `entusiastas e profissionais`.

> O que vem a ser a quebra de linha (`\n`)? Como ela funciona na linguagem `r`?

É um caractere especial que representa o término de uma linha.

Usando o seu contexto como exemplo de uso, com `multiline = TRUE`, a expressão regular "sabe" que chegou ao fim de uma linha por "encontrar" o caractere `\n`.

O funcionamento do caractere `\n` não varia de linguagem para linguagem de programação, ou entre implementações de avaliadores de expressões regulares. Trata-se de um caractere, assim como `a` ou `b`. Inclusive, [o seu código é 0d10 na tabela ASCII.](http://lsi.vc.ehu.es/asignaturas/Inf_Bas/Tablas%20ascii/Ascii%20Table%20-%20ASCII%20character%20codes%20and%20html,%20octal,%20hex%20and%20decimal%20charts_archivos/ascii2_archivos/ascii-full.gif)

No mais, recomendo também um site legal para você experimentar e aprender mais sobre regex, o [RegExr](https://regexr.com/).

Answer (score -3):

Não domino muito o RegExp, mas acho que poderia tentar algo assim:

**`"(.|\s)*"`** ou **`\n`**