# Como usar o operador de negação em expressões regulares para uma sequência específica de caracteres?

Tags: python, regex

Estudando o operador de negação em expressão regulares (`[^]`) regulares, eu entendi que é possível negar um caracter isolado (e.g., `[^x]`: qualquer coisa que não seja "x") ou um range de caracteres (e.g., `[^A-Z]`: qualquer coisa que não seja uma letra maiúscula).

No entanto, estou diante de uma situação concreta em que preciso proibir uma sequência específica de caracteres e não estou sabendo como resolver. Abaixo apresento um exemplo que replica o problema que estou tendo, bem como relato o que tentei até aqui.

Digamos que eu tenha uma lista com dados de livros, como autor e título. Segue um exemplo de uma lista desse tipo:

```
books = ["LEAL, Victor Nunes. Coronelismo, enxada e voto", 
"FLORY, Thomas. Judge and Jury in Imperial Brazil, 1808–1871: Social Control and Political Stability in the New State",
"Prado Jr., Caio. Formação do Brasil contemporâneo", "GRASS, Günter. Dog Years" , 
"ASSANGE, J.; APPELBAUM, J.; MULLER-MAGUHN, A.; ZIMMERMANN, J. Cypherpunks: Freedom and the Future of the Internet",
"BÖLL, Heinrich; VENNEWITZ, Leila. The Train Was On Time"]
```

A partir dessa lista, gostaria de retirar apenas os nomes dos autores. O que tentei até agora foi o seguinte:

```
import re

authors = []

for book in books:
    author = re.findall(r"^[A-Z-ÁÀÂÄÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÜÇÑ]+[^\.]+", book)[0]
    authors.append(author)

for author in authors:
    print(author)
```

Que resulta em:

```
LEAL, Victor Nunes
FLORY, Thomas
Prado Jr
GRASS, Günter
ASSANGE, J
BÖLL, Heinrich; VENNEWITZ, Leila
```

Note que o código funcionou para os dois primeiros autores, mas falhou no terceiro e quinto caso. Essa falha está ocorrendo porque na minha *regex* atual estou dizendo "pega o que começa com letra maiúscula seguida de qualquer sequência de caracteres, exceto um ponto final".

Fica claro que a regex não funciona no terceiro e quinto caso por conta do `.` no nome dos autores. Minha ideia então foi mudar a *regex* para algo como "pega o que começa com letra maiúscula seguida de qualquer sequência de caracteres, exceto um ponto final seguido de um espaço". Assim, usei o mesmo código acima, mas dessa vez a *regex* foi:

```
r"^[A-Z-ÁÀÂÄÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÜÇÑ]+[^\.\s]+"
```

que resultou em:

```
LEAL,
FLORY,
Prado
GRASS,
ASSANGE,
BÖLL,
```

Obviamente, não é o que esperava. Como faço para proibir a sequência `\.\s`?

Comment: Eu usei python para dar o exemplo, mas entendo que a resposta pode usar qualquer linguagem com regex similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[^\.\s]` é uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) que quer dizer "um caractere que **não** seja nem ponto nem espaço". O que está entre `[^` e `]` é uma lista de caracteres, e não há ordem definida entre eles - tanto que `[^\s\.]` é exatamente a mesma coisa.

Se quer verificar uma sequência de mais de um caractere, o jeito é usar [*lookahead negativo*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
books = ["LEAL, Victor Nunes. Coronelismo, enxada e voto", 
"FLORY, Thomas. Judge and Jury in Imperial Brazil, 1808–1871: Social Control and Political Stability in the New State",
"Prado Jr., Caio. Formação do Brasil contemporâneo", "GRASS, Günter. Dog Years" , 
"ASSANGE, J.; APPELBAUM, J.; MULLER-MAGUHN, A.; ZIMMERMANN, J. Cypherpunks: Freedom and the Future of the Internet",
"BÖLL, Heinrich; VENNEWITZ, Leila. The Train Was On Time"]

import re

authors = []
r = re.compile(r"^[A-Z-ÁÀÂÄÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÜÇÑ]+(?:(?!\.\s).)+")
for book in books:
    author = r.findall(book)[0]
    authors.append(author)

for author in authors:
    print(author)
```

No caso, `(?!\.\s)` verifica se a sequência `\.\s` **não** existe à frente. Depois eu coloco `.` que corresponde a [qualquer caractere](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (exceto [quebras de linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/372844/112052)), e toda essa sequência (um caractere, desde que não tenha um ponto seguido de espaço à frente) se repete uma ou mais vezes.

Agrupei isso com `(?:` para formar um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap), pois se usasse somente parênteses seria formado um grupo de captura, e nesse caso [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) retornaria somente os grupos.

Também usei `compile` para que a expressão seja compilada apenas uma vez, pois a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) diz que assim é mais eficiente quando você precisa usar a mesma regex várias vezes.

---

Nesse caso específico, também daria pra fazer [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) por "ponto seguido de espaço":

```
r = re.compile(r"\.\s")
for book in books:
    author = r.split(book)[0]
    authors.append(author)
```

Ou ainda sem regex:

```
author = book.split('. ')[0]
```

Lembrando que em regex o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s` não pega somente espaços, mas também quebras de linha e [vários outros caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052). Se quer considerar somente o espaço (e não os demais caracteres que `\s` pega), basta mudar para `r"^[A-Z-ÁÀÂÄÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÜÇÑ]+(?:(?!\. ).)+"` - repare que há um espaço entre o `\.` e o `)` (e no caso do `split`, ficaria `r"\. "` - com um espaço antes das aspas de fechamento).

Comment: Caramba. Você é o mago da regex. Muito obrigado!