# Como funcionam quantificadores gulosos e não gulosos?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
import requests
#o req vai ser a requisição á uma página
print(re.findall(r'(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])',req.text))
```

O código é para pegar links em uma página web.

Eu sei que ele está certo mas acabei acertando sem saber  o que estava fazendo, queria entender como funciona o ponto de interrogação nesse caso.

Comment: "Codificadores gulosos" ou "quantificadores gulosos"?

Comment: Já tem explicações sobre os quantificadores  [aqui](/q/415757/112052), [aqui](/a/401755/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94094/112052), serve?

Comment: Mas enfim, se quer extrair todos os  `href` de um HTML, não deveria usar regex e sim alguma lib dedicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052

Comment: @anonimo , quantificadores, falei errado

Comment: @hkotsubo , na verdade não serve pq estão em javascript e o que está em python eu acho que não ta utilizando a biblioteca re que é a do meu codigo

Comment: Mas a explicação sobre o `?` é a mesma independente da linguagem

Comment: Olá Rafa, recomendo que leia [O que é uma Expressão Regular gulosa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94094/3635) e depois leia: [Por que Regex não deve ser utilizado para tratar HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/3635) ... e mais alguns links em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+pegar+links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não sabe muito bem o que está fazendo, eu sugiro que não use regex para isso, existem soluções melhores (e ao longo da resposta entenderemos os motivos).

---

Mas enfim, sobre o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`: por padrão ele é "guloso" ou "ganancioso" (em inglês, chamam de [*greedy*](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap)), ou seja, ele tenta pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres.

E como você usou junto com o ponto (que corresponde a [qualquer caractere](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) - [exceto quebras de linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/372844/112052)), então `.+` acaba pegando "tudo".

Mas como depois tem `(?=["\'])`, que verifica se tem aspas, então o que `.+` faz é ir até o final da string, e depois começa a voltar até encontrar um `"` ou `'` (este comportamento é explicado em detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482807/112052)). Isso quer dizer que a regex acaba pegando tudo desde o primeiro `href` até a última aspas.

Mas se você usar `.+?`, o quantificador se torna [*lazy*/preguiçoso/não-guloso](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution), passando a pegar a menor quantidade possível de caracteres (isso é explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415757/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052) e no [link já citado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482807/112052) - e apesar destes links não serem em Python, o comportamento do quantificador *lazy* é o mesmo, por isso sugiro que leia para entender melhor). Com isso, ele pega somente o que está entre as aspas depois do `href`. Por isso "funciona".

Só pra constar, também poderia ser assim:

```
print(re.findall(r'href=["\'](https?://[^"\']+)["\']', req.text))
```

Em vez do ponto, eu uso `[^"\']`, indicando que eu quero qualquer coisa que **não** seja aspas (o `[^` indica uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)), assim eu não preciso usar o quantificador *lazy*, pois eu já garanto que a regex vai parar quando encontrar alguma aspas.

---

Mas como já dito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052) (e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052), e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)), regex não é a solução ideal. O melhor é usar uma lib dedicada, como por exemplo o [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^https?://')):
    print(a['href'])
```

Repare que usei uma regex somente para verificar se o `href` começa com "http" ou "https". Mas aqui há uma diferença fundamental: a garantia de que só estou olhando o atributo de `href` de tags `a` de um HTML.

Isso faz diferença, por exemplo, se uma das tags está comentada:

```html
<!--
comentário etc...
<a href="http://www.google.com/abc/xyz">fad fa</a>
-->
<p>blablabla</p>
<a href="https://www.abc.com">fafdafadsfsdad fa</a>
```

A regex pega os 2 links acima, o Beautiful Soup só pega o segundo ([www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)). Para que a regex consiga detectar que a tag está dentro de um comentário, [ficaria bem complicado](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42097865).

No [link já citado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052) tem muitos outros casos que uma regex pode falhar, enquanto que o Beautiful Soup (ou qualquer outro *parser* de HTML) consegue lidar normalmente, sem problemas.

[Regex são legais](https://xkcd.com/208/) - eu gosto bastante - e muitas vezes *parece* ser a melhor solução. [Mas nem sempre é](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) (para manipular HTML, [com certeza não é](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)).

Comment: muito obrigado!