# Localizar e substituir utilizando Regex no Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Escrevi alguns `imports` em centenas de arquivos do projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada arquivo tem um `import` com seu nome, mas agora preciso substituir todos os `imports` para algo genérico

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no visual studio code tem a possibilidade de fazer buscas por expressão regular:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que minha busca não seleciona o `import todo (import { ARGS } from "./accordion.stories";)`

para que eu possa substituir todos imports nos demais arquivos por: `import { ARGS } from "./mock"`

É possível incluir algum `regex` para isso?

Tentei usando o \g mas não tive sucesso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que os caracteres `{` e `}` possuem significado especial em regex (servem para definir [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), como por exemplo `[a-z]{2,5}` para "no mínimo duas, no máximo 5 letras de `a` a `z`").

Se quer que a regex considere os próprios caracteres, e não que sejam interpretados como um quantificador, basta fazer o escape com `\` - ou seja, em vez de `{` e `}`, use `\{` e `\}`:

```
import \{ ARGS \} from ".+"
```

Depois, você precisa incluir o texto entre aspas. Eu coloquei `".+"`, que significa "aspas, seguido de um ou mais caracteres (`.+`), seguido de aspas". Como o ponto por padrão pega [qualquer caractere](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), exceto [quebras de linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/372844/112052), não há risco da regex "invadir" outras linhas.

Depois, na string de substituição basta colocar `import { ARGS } from "./mock"`, que a substituição é feita corretamente.

Por fim, vale lembrar que a opção "g" que você tentou usar não faz parte da regex em si. Isso é uma [*flag* do JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) para indicar que deve substituir todas as ocorrências, mas no VSCode já existe o botão de "*Replace All*", portanto não precisa desta opção (na verdade, ela sequer é suportada).

Comment: incrível! ótima resposta!