# Regex para string que termina com letra seguida de números

Tags: java, regex

Eu estou querendo imprimir um erro caso as últimas posições sejam números antecedidos por X.

Entrada:

```
BBAAX3450
```

Saída:

```
(999, 999)
```

---

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Drone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int Y = 0;
        int X = 0;


        System.out.print("Entre com o comando: ");
        String entrada = sc.nextLine();

        if (entrada.matches("[xX][0-9]*")) {
            System.out.printf("(999, 999)");
        } else {
            Boolean continuar = true;
        while (continuar == true) {
            String removendoX = entrada.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z&&[^xX]][xX]", "");
            continuar = !removendoX.equals(entrada);
            entrada = removendoX.toUpperCase();
        }

        entrada = entrada.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]\\d[xX]$", "");

        System.out.println(entrada);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer:

```java
if (entrada.matches(".*[xX]\\d+")) {
    System.out.printf("(999, 999)");
}
```

O problema do método `matches` é que ele verifica se a string inteira corresponde à expressão. No seu caso, `matches("[xX][0-9]*")` verifica se a string inteira é um X seguido de números (mas não é, porque tem mais caracteres antes do X).

Então eu fiz algo que considere todo o conteúdo da string:

- `.*`: zero ou mais caracteres
- `[xX]`: a letra "x" minúscula ou maiúscula
- `\\d+`: um ou mais dígitos (você usou `*`, que significa "zero ou mais", mas não está claro se pode ter zero dígitos depois do X; se tiver pelo menos um, prefira usar `+`)

Um detalhe é que `.*` considera também "zero caracteres", ou seja, a string poderia ser apenas "X123". Mas se quer que tenha pelo menos algum caractere antes do "X", troque para `.+` (um ou mais caracteres).

---

Indo um pouco além, o ponto na verdade considera [quaisquer caracteres, exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/372844/112052)). Se a string não tiver quebras de linha no meio, então a solução acima funciona. Mas caso tenha, basta trocar para:

```java
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(".*x\\d+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);

// string contém quebras de linha (o "\n"), mas termina com X seguido de números
String entrada = "BBA\nABC\nX3450";
if (regex.matcher(entrada).matches()) {
    System.out.printf("(999, 999)");
}
```

Usei a *flag* `Pattern.DOTALL` para que o ponto também considere quebras de linha, e aproveitei para usar `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`, para não diferenciar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Desta forma, a regex pode ter apenas `x` em vez de `[xX]`, que mesmo assim ela considera o "X" maiúsculo.

Claro que se a string não tiver quebras de linha, isso não é necessário. Ainda sim, [é interessante usar um `Pattern`, caso a regex vá ser usada várias vezes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2469275).

---

Com `Pattern`, você também pode usar o método `find`, que ao contrário de `matches`, não verifica se a string inteira corresponde à expressão. Só que aí você precisa indicar explicitamente que o padrão deve estar no final da string, adicionando o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$` (que indica "fim da string"):

```
// use $ para indicar o final da string
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("x\\d+$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
String entrada = "BBA\nABC\nX3450";
if (regex.matcher(entrada).find()) { // <-- usar find em vez de matches
    System.out.printf("(999, 999)");
}
```

Repare que agora a regex não precisa do `.*` antes do X, pois `find` busca qualquer trecho da string que corresponda à expressão (ao contrário de `matches`, que verifica se a string inteira bate com a regex). Por isso precisa deixar claro que queremos isso somente no final, colocando o `$`.